# Help with recursive query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I've following problem, which I've not been able to do successfully. Your help will be appreciated. I'm using SQL 2005, and trying to do this using CTE.

Table has following 2 columns

```
DocNum    DocEntry
1              234
2              324
2              746
3              876
3              764
4              100
4              387
```

Expected result is as follows

```
1                 234
2                 324, 746
3                 876, 764
4                 100, 387
```

Thanks
Rahul Jain

---

Further explanation transcribed from the comments:

I'm using a query like following:

```
WITH ABC (DocNum, DocEntry) AS
   (SELECT DocNum, Cast(DocEntry As VARCHAR(8000))
        FROM Temp5
        WHERE DocNum = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.DocNum, A.DocEntry + ', ' + B.DocEntry
        FROM ABC B INNER JOIN Temp5 A ON B.DocNum +1= A.DocNum
         WHERE A.DOCNUM > 1)
SELECT * FROM ABC;
```

Result from above query is as follows

```
1 234
2 234, 324
2 234, 746
3 234, 746, 876
3 234, 746, 764
```

I dont want those numbers to repeat as shown in question.

Comment: You're going to have to be more descriptive if you want an answer.

Comment: Question looks pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: I'm using a query like following

WITH ABC (DocNum, DocEntry) AS
(SELECT DocNum, Cast(DocEntry As VARCHAR(8000))
FROM Temp5 WHERE DocNum = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT a.DocNum, A.DocEntry + ', ' + B.DocEntry  
FROM ABC B INNER JOIN Temp5 A 
ON B.DocNum +1= A.DocNum WHERE A.DOCNUM > 1)

SELECT * FROM ABC

Comment: result from above query is as follows
1    234

2    234, 324

2    234, 746

3    234, 746, 876

3    234, 746, 764
I dont want those numbers to repeat as shown in question.

Comment: Rahul - put these comments as updates to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    DocNum,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(DocEntry AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [text()]
        FROM Temp5 b
        WHERE a.DocNum = b.DocNum
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS DocEntry
FROM Temp5 a
GROUP BY DocNum
```

Itzik Ben-Gan in his excellent book [T-SQL QUERYING](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623139) has some specialized solutions for aggregate string concatenation. The query screams for itself.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an article that describes methods to do that:

[Converting Multiple Rows into a CSV String](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/converting-multiple-rows-into-a-csv-string-set-based-method)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think CTE's are the complete answer to your problem. What you're after is a PIVOT query where the number of columns in the PIVOT are unknown at query time. This question and answer looks like what you're after:

[PIVOT in sql 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198716/pivot-in-sql-2005)

[PIVOT in sql 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198716/pivot-in-sql-2005#199763)

From the example in the above answer, this is the SQL modified for your table (which I've named 'q395075' - so you just need to replace with your table name):

```
DECLARE @sql AS varchar(max)
DECLARE @pivot_list AS varchar(max) -- Leave NULL for COALESCE technique
DECLARE @select_list AS varchar(max) -- Leave NULL for COALESCE technique

SELECT @pivot_list = COALESCE(@pivot_list + ', ', '') + '[' + CONVERT(varchar, PIVOT_CODE) + ']'
        ,@select_list = COALESCE(@select_list + ', ', '') + '[' + CONVERT(varchar, PIVOT_CODE) + '] AS [col_' + CONVERT(varchar, PIVOT_CODE) + ']'
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT PIVOT_CODE
    FROM (
        SELECT DocNum, DocEntry, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocNum ORDER BY DocEntry) AS PIVOT_CODE
        FROM q395075
    ) AS rows
) AS PIVOT_CODES

SET @sql = '
;WITH p AS (
    SELECT DocNum, DocEntry, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocNum ORDER BY DocEntry) AS PIVOT_CODE
    FROM q395075
)
SELECT DocNum, ' + @select_list + '
FROM p
PIVOT (
    MIN(DocEntry)
    FOR PIVOT_CODE IN (
        ' + @pivot_list + '
    )
) AS pvt
'

PRINT @sql

EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: AntiSanta - Is it possible to concatenate all those values coming in different columns, into one column.

Comment: Take a look at Turnkey's answer, that seems to do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395075/help-with-recursive-query#395090

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #a(DocNum int,  DocEntry int)

insert into #a
select 1,234 union all
select 2,324 union all
select 2,746 union all
select 3,876 union all
select 3,764 union all
select 4,100 union all
select 4,387 


select
    DocNum,
    stuff((
        select ',' + convert(varchar(25),t.DocEntry)
        from #a t
        where t.DocNum = t1.DocNum
        order by t.DocEntry
        for xml path('')
    ),1,1,'') as name_csv
from #a t1
group by DocNum
;
```

### Output

DocNum      name_sv

```
   1    234    
   2    324,746    
   3    764,876    
   4    100,387
```

Comment: I'd suggest to add a few words in text as to why and how this is an answer. Just makes it easier to understand.