# SQL x-ref query to return a single row of a variable number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select

I have a table of `parents` (real mom & dad parent names in a table), a table of `children` (these are children of the parents, first and last name) and an `x-ref` table: xref-id, parent-id and child-id.

The xref table is to accommodate the variable number of children a mom/dad combo could have.

I need a query to return a single row of parents and children names. The problem I am facing is some parents have 1 child, some have more than 1 child.

I'm quite stumped...

```
TLB_PARENT:
p_id, momfname, dadfname

TLB_CHILD:
c_id, childfname, childlname

TLB_XREF
xref_id, p_id, c_id
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want/need a query that completely denormalizes a perfectly normalized structure that you have?

Comment: Check this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: Or this (for a different approach, using PIVOT and resulting in 10 columns for the 10 child names - with some NULLs): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198716/pivot-in-sql-2005

Comment: By using an external table for linking children and parents you enable children to belong to more than one couple of parents. I think you should put the `p_id` reference directly into the `TBL_CHILD` table instead.

Answer (score 0):

The number of culmns is a SQL Query is not dynamic, it's very firmly fixed.

The closest you can get is deciding on a maximum number of children.  You'll then have blanks in many cells, but more importantly, the possibility that the table gets filled and some children don't get displayed.

How to do this depends on the version of SQL you have.

Also, note that you can have this scenario in real life...

- WomanA and ManA have ChildA
- WomanA and ManB have ChildB
- WomanB and ManB have ChildC
- WomanB and ManA have ChildD

Although that's a bit of a messy world, I know some really really messy families.  I'm just pointing out that your simplification is likely to have issues in any decent sized real world population.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in this project there is a maximum of 10 children allowed per couple. Also, we control the combos in that it will be strictly man/woman-A have child1, child2, childn (max of 10).

Comment: What version of SQL?  (Hopefully someone else will give an example for you, I have to leave work now.  Have a good weekend)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 is what we are using. - again thank you for any replies!