# Most efficient way of Searching for a list of values in an SQL table

Tags: sql, algorithm

I have a SQL table like this:-

```
a | b | c | d
```

4 columns. It gets around 80 million entries per day

I will pass a list of column c values. What is the best way to retrieve the rows from this table with those column c values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697367/loop-through-columns-sql/12634334#12634334 by simplified it in your scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficient search, an index shall be created on the column. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp

And for filtering based on a list of values, you could use "in" operator in select query as given below.

SELECT * FROM table WHERE c IN (value1,value2,...);

If you have any further doubts, please add in the comments.

Comment: the index is created on this table on a different column. Column "a" is the indexed column.

Comment: But you could add up another index on C column as your query requires that .. It is fine to create multiple indexes

Comment: Thanks karthikeyan