# Concat groups in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, string-concatenation

If I have a table like this:

```
+------------+
| Id | Value |
+------------+
| 1  | 'A'   |
|------------|
| 1  | 'B'   |
|------------|
| 2  | 'C'   |
+------------+
```

How can I get a resultset like this:

```
+------------+
| Id | Value |
+------------+
| 1  | 'AB'  |
|------------|
| 2  | 'C'   |
+------------+
```

I know this is really easy to do in MySQL using GROUP_CONCAT, but I need to be able to do it in MSSQL 2005

Thanks

(Duplicate of [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mssql))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a clean and efficient solution you can create [an user defined aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190678.aspx), there is even [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx) that does just what you need.
You can then use it like any other aggregate function (with a standard query plan):

[image: query plan]

Comment: the most clean solution yet

Answer (score 5):

This will do:

```
SELECT mt.ID,
       SUBSTRING((SELECT mt2.Value
                  FROM   MyTable AS mt2
                  WHERE  mt2.ID = mt.ID
                  ORDER BY mt2.VALUE
                  FOR XML PATH('')), 3, 2000) AS JoinedValue
FROM   MyTable AS mt
```

Comment: This concats the values in a XML document, which is undesirable.

Comment: No, it uses XML functions.  There are no XML documents involved.  Why is it "undesirable"?

Answer (score 4):

See:

http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html

Comment: Please find my blog covering scenarios for grouped concatenation in SQL server. https://blog.vcillusion.co.in/understanding-the-grouped-concatenation-sql-server/

Comment: Without using Value with XML-PATH might lead to parsing errors for XML encoded values.

Answer (score 3):

Often [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-mssql-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-subquery).

The most efficient way is using the FOR XML PATH trick.

Comment: Also, we have STRING_AGG
Introduced in SQL Server (starting with 2017), it concatenates the values of string expressions and places separator values between them (not added at the end of the string). https://blog.vcillusion.co.in/understanding-the-grouped-concatenation-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

This just came to me as one possible solution. I have no idea as to performance, but I thought it would be an interesting way to solve the problem. I tested that it works in a simple situation (I didn't code to account for NULLs). Feel free to give it a test to see if it performs well for you.

The table that I used included an id (my_id). That could really be any column that is unique within the group (grp_id), so it could be a date column or whatever.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT
        T1.my_id,
        T1.grp_id,
        CAST(T1.my_str AS VARCHAR) AS my_str
    FROM
        dbo.Test_Group_Concat T1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Test_Group_Concat T2 WHERE T2.grp_id = T1.grp_id AND T2.my_id < T1.my_id)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        T3.my_id,
        T3.grp_id,
        CAST(CTE.my_str + T3.my_str AS VARCHAR)
    FROM
        CTE
    INNER JOIN dbo.Test_Group_Concat T3 ON
        T3.grp_id = CTE.grp_id AND
        T3.my_id > CTE.my_id
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Test_Group_Concat T4 WHERE
        T4.grp_id = CTE.grp_id AND
        T4.my_id > CTE.my_id AND
        T4.my_id < T3.my_id)
)
SELECT
    CTE.grp_id,
    CTE.my_str
FROM
    CTE
INNER JOIN (SELECT grp_id, MAX(my_id) AS my_id FROM CTE GROUP BY grp_id) SQ ON
    SQ.grp_id = CTE.grp_id AND
    SQ.my_id = CTE.my_id
ORDER BY
    CTE.grp_id
```