# TSQL How to build a string dynamically?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

let's say that I have a table with columns like this:

```
| Name | Cat_id |
```

I cannot remember the function which can build a varchar like this

```
1,24|4,56|5,67
```

where the number before the comma is the `Cat_id`, and the number after comma is the count of rows with that ID. Any ideas ?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941103/concat-groups-in-sql-server

Comment: Are the pipe symbol part of the output? Is the output just 1 line with pipe delimited values of cat_id, count(cat_id) or you are expecting one row per cat_id?

Answer (score 3):

This could do the trick:

```
declare @s varchar(8000)
set     @s = ''

select  @s = @s + cast(cat_id as varchar(20)) + ',' + cast(count(*) as varchar(20)) + '|'
from    SomeTable
group by cat_id
option(maxdop 1) -- this sure there are no funny side-effects because of parallelism

print @s
```

Alternatively you could use 'for xml', or a cursor, but this should be faster.

Regards GJ

Comment: hm, the count(*) returns always 1, even if I create a subquery (select count(*) from SomeTable where cat_id = st.cat_id) instead of that count(*)

Comment: Should work... sure you dont just hae unique id's? (not unlikely...)

Comment: Crap, sorry, read it wrong. Make it @S = @s + name + ',' .. etc .. group by name. We're grouping on Cat_id instead of name. EDIT: nope, you did ask for group by cat_id. You sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help(sql server 2005+)... I have not tested the program as I donot have SQL Server at present

```
With Cte1 As(
Select Cat_ID, Count(Cat_ID),Cast(Cat_ID as Varchar) + Cast(Count(Cat_ID)) as MergedColumn from tbl 
group by Cat_ID),
cte2 as(
Select 
    Cat_ID
    , mergedData  = stuff((Select cast(MergedColumn + '|' as varchar) from tbl t2 where t2.Cat_ID  = t1.Cat_ID 
                  for xml path('')),1,1,'')
from tbl t1)

select mergedData from Cte2
```