# Concatenating multiple rows fields into one column in T-SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql

I am writing an SQL query in which that I will need to perform a sub select on a table, which will usually return multiple rows. I need to be able to join together the results of a certain field from all the rows into one field to output. Is this possible, and how?

For example, if the SQL query returns

```
id | field
1  | test1
2  | test2
3  | test3
```

I need the outputted field to be "test1 test2 test3".
Thanks

Comment: Exact duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941103/concat-groups-in-sql-server and many other questions.

Comment: ...and I assume the answerers have not read this http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

Comment: @gbn: Well, I've read that blog post.  It does not list one successful long tail answer, and I don't think they exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @sample table(id int, field varchar(20))
insert into @sample values(1,'test1')
insert into @sample values(2,'test2')
insert into @sample values(3,'test3')
declare @result varchar(max) set @result = ''
select @result = @result + ' '+field from @sample
select @result
```

A SQLCLR custom aggregator would be a an alternative (read better) solution

Answer (score 5):

Here's the `for xml` trick to do that:

```
    SELECT  field + ' ' as [text()]
    FROM    YourTable
    FOR XML PATH ('')
```

This prints:

```
test1 test2 test3
```

It's typically used with an `outer apply` to execute it once for each row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT RTRIM(field)
  FROM (
                SELECT field + ' ' field
                    FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
                    FOR XML PATH('')
             ) a
```

Comment: On my machine, this gives: `No column name was specified for column 1 of 'a'.`

Comment: Updated the post to reflect the column name as specified.

Comment: You'd have to change `) a` to `) a(field)`; then it would print `<field1>field1 </field1><field1>field2 </field1><field1>field3 </field1>`, which you can fix by changing `SELECT field + ' ' field` to `SELECT field + ' ' as [text()]`

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the existing answers. Try including the [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) expression with column name your going to use. This avoids having null values in your concatenated string and avoid your list looking like this. Notice the redundant blank space.

```
field1 field2   field4 field
```

Further details can be found [here](http://blog.zirafon.org/concatenating_multiple_rows_into_one_column_in_t_sql/).

```
GO

DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @tableName = COALESCE(@tableName + ' ' ,'') + Name
FROM    sys.tables
SELECT  @tableName

GO
```

Answer (score -1):

it is possible to do with a cursor.

```
declare @field nvarchar(max)
declare @concat nvarchar(max)
set @concat = ''
declare @cursor cursor
set @cursor = cursor for select field from table
open @cursor
fetch next from @cursor into @field
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  set @concat = concat(@concat,@field)
  fetch next from @cursor into @field
end
```

your exercise is to add space between the concatenated strings :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141/why-is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-use-cursors-in-sql-server