# How to combine multiple rows in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)
>   [Concat groups in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941103/concat-groups-in-sql-server)

I am trying to write an SQL query that will combine rows together. I need it to group together an unspecified number of rows by ID# but concatenate their addresses let's say into one cell.

Say we have

```
ID, Address
p1 a1
p1 a2
p1 a3
p2 a4
p2 a5
```

I want to get

```
ID, Address
p1 a1,a2,a3
p2 a4,a5
```

The number of addresses per ID can vary. Some IDs have 1, others can have 50.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select T1.Id
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select ', ' + T2.Address
        From MyTable As T2
        Where T2.Id = T1.Id
        Order By T2.Address
        For Xml Path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') As Address
From MyTable As T1
Group By T1.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

The Coalesce function can be used to produce that result.  Coalesce returns the first non null value in a set.  If you use it in the following manner it will recursivly return each value in order until it nulls out and return it as a comma delimited string.  You can use any other delimiter if you want.

```
DECLARE @pAddr VarChar(MAX)
SELECT @pAddr = COALESCE(@pAddr + ', ', '') + [Address]
FROM AddressTable
WHERE AddressTable.Key = @pKey
```

You could put this code into a UDF, and then in a view simply call that UDF passing the key.