# Optimizing SQL Query...

Tags: sql-server

I have data in my table as following:

> ```
> Author ID  Book Name
>
> A1    Book1
>
> A1    Book2
>
> A2    Book4
>
> A2    Book5
> ```

I want to represent the data as

> ```
> A1  Book1,Book2
>
> A2  Book3,Book5
> ```

How I can do that without using a temporary table?

Answer (score 0):

This question is already asked and answered.Check the questions before you post.

Edit this code according to your column.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967469/how-to-combine-multiple-rows-in-mssql?lq=1)

```
   Select T1.Id
    , Stuff(
        (
        Select ', ' + T2.Address
        From MyTable As T2
        Where T2.Id = T1.Id
        Order By T2.Address
        For Xml Path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') As Address
From MyTable As T1
Group By T1.Id
```

Comment: Please flag questions as duplicates, and don't just re-post the answer. This question will be closed as a duplicate soon.