# Query to transform table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is as below

```
SELECT SupplierId,StakeholderSupplierId,Percentage
FROM std_Stakeholders    
ORDER BY SupplierId
```

which yields me result as below

```
SupplierId        StakeholderSupplierId             Percentage
1                          3175                        68.00
2929                       5504                        25.00
5504                        1                          68.25
5504                       3238                        50.00
5504                       2810                        23.00
```

I want to transform this output as .

```
  SupplierId    StakeholderSupplierId1  Percentage  StakeholderSupplierId2  Percentage StakeholderSupplierId3   Percentage
    1                    3175            68.00  
    2929                 5504            25.00
    5504                  1              68.68             3238                50.00                2810            23.00
```

I tried with joins and pivoting . couldn't succeed in writing a proper query to get the desired output . Can anyone help me out

Note: StakeholderSupplierId is not static  . it may vary from 1 to n

Comment: how do that help ? . its not recursive . its just transformation of row to columns with row numbers

Comment: it is recursive: you are looking for unique supplierids, if you see a repeat then you put the data in the next column

Comment: sorry im wrong it's not recursive

Comment: How can that result come from that query?  It says `WHERE SupplierId=5504`, yet the result has all kinds of supplier IDs.

Comment: sorry fa ma mistake . I corrected it now

Comment: You'll need to write dynamic sql since you don't know the max number of stakeholders.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a solution for your problem (depends on what you need to do after this query), but for problems like this I have use the MySQL `GROUP_CONCAT` function. For a similar solution in SQL Server check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941103/concat-groups-in-sql-server) question.

With a `GROUP_CONCAT` function you can get a result table like this:

```
SupplierId    StakeholderSupplierIds  Percentages  
1             3175                    68.00  
2929          5504                    25.00
5504          1, 3238, 2810           68.68, 50.00, 23.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this with a two-step process but equally I expect it is possible with a `PIVOT` - however as an example (old style approach for the last step):

```
declare @stakeholdersForPivot table
(
  SupplierId int,
  StakeholderId int,
  StakeholderSupplierId int,
  Percentage decimal(19,2)
)

; with orderedStakeholders as
(
  select SupplierId
  , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by SupplierId order By StakeholderSupplierId) StakeholderId
  ,StakeholderSupplierId, Percentage
  from std_Stakeholders

)

insert into @stakeholdersForPivot (SupplierId, StakeholderId, StakeholderSupplierId, Percentage)
select SupplierId, StakeholderId, StakeholderSupplierId, Percentage
from orderedStakeholders

select SupplierId
, sum(case when StakeholderId = 1 then StakeholderSupplierId else null end) StakeholderSupplierId1
, sum(case when StakeholderId = 1 then Percentage else null end) Percentage1
, sum(case when StakeholderId = 2 then StakeholderSupplierId else null end) StakeholderSupplierId2
, sum(case when StakeholderId = 2 then Percentage else null end) Percentage2
, sum(case when StakeholderId = 3 then StakeholderSupplierId else null end) StakeholderSupplierId3
, sum(case when StakeholderId = 3 then Percentage else null end) Percentage3
from @stakeholdersForPivot
group by SupplierId
order by SupplierId
```

Obviously you have to be explicit about the maximum number of stakeholder suppliers you're expecting per supplier but you can extend this as required.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query that uses the "GROUP BY MAX" trick. Should work across databases. The drawback is that the columns list is static.

```
SELECT
    supplierid,
    max(StakeholderSupplierId1) AS StakeholderSupplierId1,
    max(percentage1) AS percentage,
    max(StakeholderSupplierId2) AS StakeholderSupplierId2,
    max(percentage2) AS percentage,
    max(StakeholderSupplierId3) AS StakeholderSupplierId3,
    max(percentage3) AS percentage
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            supplierid,
            CASE WHEN ranking = 1 THEN stakeholdersupplierid END AS StakeholderSupplierId1,
            CASE WHEN ranking = 1 THEN percentage END AS percentage1,
            CASE WHEN ranking = 2 THEN stakeholdersupplierid END AS StakeholderSupplierId2,
            CASE WHEN ranking = 2 THEN percentage END AS percentage2,
            CASE WHEN ranking = 3 THEN stakeholdersupplierid END AS StakeholderSupplierId3,
            CASE WHEN ranking = 3 THEN percentage END AS percentage3
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    supplierid,
                    stakeholdersupplierid,
                    percentage,
                    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY supplierid ORDER BY percentage DESC) AS ranking
                FROM
                    std_stakeholders
            ) AS t
    ) AS t
GROUP BY
    supplierid
;
```