# comma separated result multiple columns sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table with values:

```
Key1     Key2     ColumnKey 
============================
1        idx1      here
2        idx2      there
```

I need to return, for more than one column result seperated by commas.

Example:

```
1,2   idx1,idx2,      here,there
```

Comment: Same as Same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941103/concat-groups-in-sql-server I think

Comment: I had the solution, but was only for one column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select stuff(T.X.query('Key1').value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as Key1,
       stuff(T.X.query('Key2').value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as Key2,
       stuff(T.X.query('ColumnKey').value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as ColumnKey
from 
  (
  select ','+cast(Key1 as varchar(10)) as Key1,
         ','+Key2 as Key2,
         ','+ColumnKey as ColumnKey
  from YourTable
  order by Key1
  for xml path(''), type
  ) T(X)
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/78673?)

Comment: Can someone share the name of the technique used here? Specifically the T(X) => T.X.query('Key1')

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
;WITH CTE as(
select *,1 rn from test101)
select (STUFF((select ','+cast(Key1 as varchar(10)) from CTE  where CTE.rn=m.rn for xml path('')),1,1,'')) key1,
(STUFF((select ','+Key2  from CTE  where CTE.rn=m.rn for xml path('')),1,1,'')) key2,
(STUFF((select ','+ColumnKey from CTE  where CTE.rn=m.rn for xml path('')),1,1,'')) ColumnKey
from CTE m
group by rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that CodePlex has an open-source CLR implementation  of user defined aggregate **GROUP_CONCAT** .Installation is as simple as running a SQL script on your server.

http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/

it has 4 group_concat implementation

- GROUP_CONCAT    --default delimiter is , (comma)
- GROUP_CONCAT_D  -- you can specify the delimiter
- GROUP_CONCAT_DS -- you can specify the delimiter ,sort order (1 as asc order ,2 as desc order)
- GROUP_CONCAT_S  -- you can specify sort order