# How to add data from table to string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Have table `@tbl` with `INT` data :

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
```

want select this id-s and set to `declare @myStr nvarchar(max)` with " | "
It must be like : 1|2|3|4|5|
how to do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concat groups in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941103/concat-groups-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following Query:

```
declare @myStr nvarchar(max)

set @myStr=(SELECT STUFF((
SELECT '|' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,ID)
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''))

SELECT @myStr
```