# Join two tables and concatenate multiple rows of a single field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 (ID int)
CREATE TABLE #Temp2 (ID int, Value varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #Temp1 (ID)
SELECT 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT 3

INSERT INTO #Temp2(ID, Value)
SELECT 1,'One-One'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'One-Two'
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'One-One'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Two-One'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Two-Two'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Two-One'

SELECT T1.ID, T2.Value FROM #Temp1 T1 INNER JOIN #Temp2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID

DROP TABLE #Temp1
DROP TABLE #Temp2
```

Current Output:

```
ID  Value
1   One-One
1   One-Two
1   One-One
2   Two-One
2   Two-Two
2   Two-One
```

Desired Output:

```
ID  Values
1,  One-One, One-Two, One-One
2,  Two-One, Two-Two, Two-One
```

I would like to join two tables, #Table1 and #Tabl2, on a key column, ID, and get Value field from the 2nd table... but in a single row (as shown in desired output).

How (if possible) can I achieve the Desired Output?

Thank you

Comment: We get so many duplicates along these lines: [Concat groups in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941103/concat-groups-in-sql-server)

Comment: thx for the reference. Next time, I will search with different keywords/strings. Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.ID,
      STUFF((SELECT ', ' + T2.Value
             FROM   #Temp2 T2 
             WHERE  T1.ID = T2.ID
             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
             .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'') AS Value
FROM #Temp1 T1 
GROUP BY T1.ID
```

**For SQL Server 2017 and Later Versions**

```
SELECT T1.ID, STRING_AGG(T2.Value , ', ') AS [Value]
FROM #Temp1 T1 
INNER JOIN #Temp2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
GROUP BY T1.ID
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════╦═══════════════════════════╗
║ ID ║           Value           ║
╠════╬═══════════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ One-One, One-Two, One-One ║
║  2 ║ Two-One, Two-Two, Two-One ║
╚════╩═══════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT Id, STUFF(A.Value, 1, 2, '') [Values] FROM #Temp1 T1
CROSS APPLY 
(
   SELECT ', ' + Value FROM #Temp2 T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID FOR XML PATH('')
) A(Value)
WHERE A.Value IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you Hamlet for showing an alternative way. Will keep this handy if the other approach doesn't work for some reason. Cheers!