# Select a row/column that has a data of 'dataname'

Tags: sql, database

is there a select query where I can find a column that has a data named 'Hello'. I'm not looking for a data on a single table, but am looking for a data on a whole database.

Comment: *Dynamic SQL* might help you with this. Also query information schema to get all column names.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12051216/330315 and here http://stackoverflow.com/q/13514509/330315 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1289792/330315 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=search+all+columns+in+a+database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@aedz: here are some suggenstions/hints for you, basically this is easy to google:

MSSQL:

- [SQL Server: Search all tables for a particular GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970477/sql-server-search-all-tables-for-a-particular-guid)
- http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/c0c57332-8624-48c0-b4c3-5b31fe641c58
- http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm
- [Search for a string in all tables, rows and columns of a DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591853/search-for-a-string-in-an-all-the-tables-rows-and-columns-of-a-db)
- http://justgeeks.blogspot.de/2006/10/search-ms-sql-server-for-any-text.html
- http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic419243-8-1.aspx
- http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1522/searching-and-finding-a-string-value-in-all-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/
- http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1555/sql-server-find-and-replace-values-in-all-tables-and-all-text-columns/

MySql:

- [Search for all occurrences of a string in a mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562457/search-for-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-a-mysql-database)
- [Search in all fields from every table of a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639531/mysql-search-in-all-fields-from-every-table-from-a-database)
- [MySQL tool that searches for a string in all fields, tables and databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624611/mysql-tool-that-searches-for-a-string-in-all-fields-tables-and-databases)
- [mySQL query to search all tables within a database for a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523039/mysql-query-to-search-all-tables-within-a-database-for-a-string)
- http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/search-through-all-databases-tables-columns-in-mysql