# How can I concatinate a subquery result field into the parent query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery, concatenation

DB: Sql Server 2008.

I have a really (fake) groovy query like this:-

```
SELECT CarId, NumberPlate
    (SELECT Owner
     FROM Owners b
     WHERE b.CarId = a.CarId) AS Owners
FROM Cars a
ORDER BY NumberPlate
```

And this is what I'm trying to get...

```
=> 1    ABC123     John, Jill, Jane
=> 2    XYZ123     Fred
=> 3    SOHOT      Jon Skeet, ScottGu
```

So, i tried using

AS `[Text()] ... FOR XML PATH('')` but that was inlcuding weird encoded characters (eg. carriage return). ... so i'm not 100% happy with that.

I also tried to see if there's a COALESCE solution, but all my attempts failed.

So - any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the solution to this question:

[How to create a SQL Server function to "join" multiple rows from a subquery into a single delimited field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-mssql-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-subquery)

:)

Comment: Ha -> that post was also using cars as an example :) I ended up creating a temp UDF, run my code, drop udf. Works great :) This is for an import process .. hence the create/drop of the udf. cheers :)

Answer (score 10):

Answering an old post, just thought it needed an update for newer versions of SQL Server:

For SQL Server 2017 use STRING_AGG(*expression*, *seperator*)

GROUP_CONCAT is MySQL.

Prior to SQL 2017, you can also do something like (snipped from our current code base on SQL Server 2016):

```
SELECT CarId, NumberPlate,
    (STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + b.Owner
        FROM Owners b
        WHERE b.CarId = a.CarId
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
        ,1,2,'')) AS Owners
FROM Cars a
ORDER BY NumberPlate
```

Links to STRING_AGG
https://database.guide/the-sql-server-equivalent-to-group_concat/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Link to STUFF:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

and finally links to FOR XML:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT CarId, NumberPlate
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Owner)
     FROM Owners b
     WHERE b.CarId = a.CarId) AS Owners
    FROM Cars a
ORDER BY NumberPlate
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT doesn't exist in Sql Server 2008. Or any version, for that matter.

Comment: It works for MySQL 5.7