# Concatenating Column Values into a Comma-Separated List

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is the TSQL syntax to format my output so that the column values appear as a string, seperated by commas.

Example, my table CARS has the following:

```
CarID    CarName  
----------------
    1    Porsche  
    2    Mercedes  
    3    Ferrari
```

How do I get the car names as : `Porsche, Mercedes, Ferrari`

Comment: group_concat(field_here, ',') if you're using MySQL. array_to_string(array_accum(field_here), ',') if you're using PostgreSQL. but since you're using MSSQL, just create a function that returns the comma-delimited string.  Use ConcernedOfTunbridgeW code snippet, put in a function

Comment: @van: The way the question is posed looks to me like at least he made an effort in trying to be as clear as possible and maintain readability, therefore, I assume he also took the trouble trying to find an answer on his own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: @van that's pretty funny, I thought your comment was recent and then I noticed it is over 5 years old; this question [is *still* asked at least once a week](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26495974/61305).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can do a shortcut using `coalesce` to concatenate a series of strings from a record in a table, for example.

```
declare @aa varchar (200)
set @aa = ''

select @aa = 
    case when @aa = ''
    then CarName
    else @aa + coalesce(',' + CarName, '')
    end
  from Cars

print @aa
```

Comment: why init @aa to '' instead of just checking `is null` in the first `when`? also, why the coalesce? lastly, don't you want to wrap `CarName` with `isnull(CarName, '')` to be safe?

Comment: Your `coalesce` is in the wrong place; it should wrap CarName like `@aa + coalesce(',' + CarName, '')` (check suggested edit) to turn CarName to a blanks tring in cases where its null. As you have it, `@aa` will be blanked out every time CarName is NULL.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells - Can this approach be used to perform dynamic SQL statements, such as: `SELECT col1 as 'col1 name', coln as 'coln name' FROM <table>` ?

Comment: @NickBraunagel yes, you can do that and I've done it before.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding brackets (`[`) around the display name to achieve this.

Answer (score 76):

For *SQL Server 2017* and newer versions see the answer by gpanagakis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41851771/218408

For *SQL Server 2016* and older versions:

```
SELECT LEFT(Car, LEN(Car) - 1)
FROM (
    SELECT Car + ', '
    FROM Cars
    FOR XML PATH ('')
  ) c (Car)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had never seen this syntax for naming the columns of a subquery. I wonder if you can edit your answer to include that part of the TSQL syntax that permits this?

Comment: It's a construction I picked up right here at Stackoverflow. I don't know where or even if it is mentioned in any TSQL specification.

Comment: I wonder if this one is any faster or slower than the "STUFF" answer below from Vaibhav... Both are great and snippet-y (re-usable)

Comment: I doubt any performance difference is noticable as the grunt of the work is the same for both solutions. But as always, try both in different scenarios and measure if you want to be sure.

Answer (score 40):

If you are running on SQL Server 2017 or Azure SQL Database you do something like this :

```
 SELECT STRING_AGG(CarName,',') as CarNames
 FROM CARS
```

Comment: It's about time this function was created!

Comment: An equivalent to LISTAGG() was a long-time coming, and should definitely be used in SQL Server 2017.

Comment: This should be upvoted!

Answer (score 29):

You can do this using stuff:

```
SELECT Stuff(
    (
    SELECT ', ' + CARS.CarName
    FROM CARS
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') AS CarNames
```

Comment: Basically just a simplified version of the answer here -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/how-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-subquery-into -- but I found this one's simplicity more portable because you can plug it into a "snippet manager" like SSMSBoost or Redgate SQLPrompt and have it saved in your own personal toolbox.

Answer (score 10):

```
DECLARE @CarList nvarchar(max);
SET @CarList = N'';
SELECT @CarList+=CarName+N','
FROM dbo.CARS;
SELECT LEFT(@CarList,LEN(@CarList)-1);
```

Thanks are due to whoever on SO showed me the use of accumulating data during a query.

Comment: If "CarName" is an int (ie, "CarId), do SELECT @CarList+=CONVERT(varchar(20),CarId,0)+N','

Answer (score 10):

Another solution within a query :

```
select 
    Id, 
    STUFF(
        (select (', "' + od.ProductName + '"')
        from OrderDetails od (nolock)
        where od.Order_Id = o.Id
        order by od.ProductName
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, ''
    ) ProductNames
from Orders o (nolock)
where o.Customer_Id = 525188
order by o.Id desc
```

(EDIT: thanks @user007 for the STUFF declaration)

Comment: Is there a solution for this in Netezza

Comment: Nice one for adding the where and order clause

Answer (score 8):

Please try this with the following code:

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' , '') + CarName
FROM Cars
SELECT @listStr
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @SQL = ISNULL(@SQL+',','') + ColumnName FROM TableName
SELECT @SQL
```

Comment: @PhilS, No, It will give correct answer, if you run the above query on employee table on the names, the sample result would be Jhon,Thomas,PhilS

Comment: @john: Oh, you are right indeed. Sorry, my fault. I would reversed the downvote, but the system does not let me unless the answer is edited...