# How do I create a comma-separated list using a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-aggregation

I have 3 tables called:

- Applications (id, name)
- Resources  (id, name)
- ApplicationsResources (id, app_id, resource_id)

I want to show on a GUI a table of all resource names. In one cell in each row I would like to list out all of the applications (comma separated) of that resource.

So the question is, what is the best way to do this in SQL as I need to get all resources and I also need to get all applications for each resource?

Do I run a select * from resources first and then loop through each resource and do a separate query per resource to get the list of applications for that resource?

Is there a way I can do this in one query?

Comment: i would like my solution to be db agnostic

Comment: @oo: String handling isn't very db agnostic.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048209/concatenating-column-values-into-a-comma-separated-list

Comment: What database product and version?

Comment: @prabhats.net: You may be new to SO, so remember to upvote helpful answers and accept the one that was most helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it in a DB-agnostic way.
So you need to get the whole data-set like this:

```
select 
  r.name as ResName, 
  a.name as AppName
from 
  Resouces as r, 
  Applications as a, 
  ApplicationsResources as ar
where
  ar.app_id = a.id 
  and ar.resource_id = r.id
```

And then concat the *AppName* **programmatically** while grouping by *ResName*.

Answer (score 139):

### MySQL

```
  SELECT r.name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(a.name SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM RESOURCES r
    JOIN APPLICATIONSRESOURCES ar ON ar.resource_id = r.id
    JOIN APPLICATIONS a ON a.id = ar.app_id
GROUP BY r.name
```

### SQL Server (2005+)

```
SELECT r.name,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + a.name
               FROM APPLICATIONS a
               JOIN APPLICATIONRESOURCES ar ON ar.app_id = a.id
              WHERE ar.resource_id = r.id
           GROUP BY a.name
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(max)'), 1, LEN(','), '')
 FROM RESOURCES r
```

### SQL Server (2017+)

```
  SELECT r.name,
         STRING_AGG(a.name, ',')
    FROM RESOURCES r
    JOIN APPLICATIONSRESOURCES ar ON ar.resource_id = r.id
    JOIN APPLICATIONS a ON a.id = ar.app_id
GROUP BY r.name
```

### Oracle

I recommend [reading about string aggregation/concatentation in Oracle](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/StringAggregationTechniques.php).

Comment: Also worth noting is that group_concat defaults to ',' separated so group_concat(a.name) is equivalent to group_concat(a.name SEPARATOR ',')

Comment: SQLite is the same as MySQL except the function looks like: `GROUP_CONCAT(a.name, ', ')`

Answer (score 35):

> ### **NOTE:**
>
> **This method is not recommended as it can give incorrect or non-deterministic results.
>
> This has been documented on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior) and [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/132709)**

**Using COALESCE to Build Comma-Delimited String in SQL Server**
http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-coalesce-to-build-comma-delimited-string

Example:

```
DECLARE @EmployeeList varchar(100)

SELECT @EmployeeList = COALESCE(@EmployeeList + ', ', '') + 
   CAST(Emp_UniqueID AS varchar(5))
FROM SalesCallsEmployees
WHERE SalCal_UniqueID = 1

SELECT @EmployeeList
```

Comment: this seems a much better solution than the higher rated answers.  Easy and versatile.

Comment: What if you want to EmployeeList per (Group by) department?

Comment: @Gary: Then add a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if there's any solution to do this in a database-agnostic way, since you most likely will need some form of string manipulation, and those are typically different between vendors.

For SQL Server 2005 and up, you could use:

```
SELECT
     r.ID, r.Name,
     Resources = STUFF(
       (SELECT ','+a.Name
        FROM dbo.Applications a
        INNER JOIN dbo.ApplicationsResources ar ON ar.app_id = a.id
        WHERE ar.resource_id = r.id
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM
     dbo.Resources r
```

It uses the SQL Server 2005 `FOR XML PATH` construct to list the subitems (the applications for a given resource) as a comma-separated list.

Marc

Comment: I believe you are missing an "r". The INNER JOIN should say "ON ar.app_id = a.id". Works for me now. Thanks.

Comment: @MagnusSmith: **absolutely!** Thanks for your "eagle eyes" spotting this typo! Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you want is:

`SELECT ItemName, GROUP_CONCAT(DepartmentId) FROM table_name GROUP BY ItemName`

If you're using MySQL

Reference

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT only works in MySQL and SQLite.  The OP said in a comment that they're using MS SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Didn't see the comment until after the post. Should I delete my answer for irrelevance or just leave it for interest?

Comment: ...years later, but for the record... I'd leave it, it's helpful & the OP's title is ambiguous. I was searching for a solution for MySQL, this question came up (it's tagged as mysql) & this answer helped me!

Comment: Your answer comes up in the serps for mysql.  Saved me hours - thanks for leaving it in.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming SQL Server:

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[item_dept](
    [ItemName] char(20) NULL,
    [DepartmentID] int NULL   
)
```

Query:

```
SELECT ItemName,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + rtrim(convert(char(10),DepartmentID))
        FROM   item_dept b
        WHERE  a.ItemName = b.ItemName
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') DepartmentID
FROM   item_dept a
GROUP BY ItemName
```

Results:

```
ItemName    DepartmentID
item1       21,13,9,36
item2       4,9,44
```

Comment: +1 This works, but IMHO this solution for SQL Server is a hack, tremendously ugly and non-intuitive.  Not your fault though. :)

Comment: There is another SQL Server solution possible with custom CLR aggregates if guaranteed Order of the delimited items is not essential.

Answer (score 4):

From [next version of SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx) you will be able to do

```
SELECT r.name,
       STRING_AGG(a.name, ',')
FROM   RESOURCES r
       JOIN APPLICATIONSRESOURCES ar
         ON ar.resource_id = r.id
       JOIN APPLICATIONS a
         ON a.id = ar.app_id
GROUP  BY r.name
```

For previous versions of the product there are quite a wide variety of different approaches to this problem. An excellent review of them is in the article: [Concatenating Row Values in Transact-SQL](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

- Concatenating values when the number of items are not known

  - Recursive CTE method
  - The blackbox XML methods
  - Using Common Language Runtime
  - Scalar UDF with recursion
  - Table valued UDF with a WHILE loop
  - Dynamic SQL
  - The Cursor approach
    .
- Non-reliable approaches

  - Scalar UDF with t-SQL update extension
  - Scalar UDF with variable concatenation in SELECT

Answer (score 4):

I think we could write in the following way to retrieve(below code is just an example, please modify as needed):

```
Create FUNCTION dbo.ufnGetEmployeeMultiple(@DepartmentID int)
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000) AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @Employeelist varchar(1000)

SELECT @Employeelist = COALESCE(@Employeelist + ', ', '') + E.LoginID
FROM humanresources.Employee E

Left JOIN humanresources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory H ON
E.BusinessEntityID = H.BusinessEntityID

INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department D ON
H.DepartmentID = D.DepartmentID

Where H.DepartmentID = @DepartmentID

Return @Employeelist

END

SELECT D.name as Department, dbo.ufnGetEmployeeMultiple (D.DepartmentID)as Employees
FROM HumanResources.Department D

SELECT Distinct (D.name) as Department, dbo.ufnGetEmployeeMultiple (D.DepartmentID) as 
Employees
FROM HumanResources.Department D
```

Answer (score 2):

**MySQL**

```
  SELECT r.name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(a.name SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM RESOURCES r
    JOIN APPLICATIONSRESOURCES ar ON ar.resource_id = r.id
    JOIN APPLICATIONS a ON a.id = ar.app_id
GROUP BY r.name
```

**

---

**MS SQL Server**

```
SELECT r.name,
       STUFF((SELECT ','+ a.name
               FROM APPLICATIONS a
               JOIN APPLICATIONRESOURCES ar ON ar.app_id = a.id
              WHERE ar.resource_id = r.id
           GROUP BY a.name
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')
 FROM RESOURCES r
 GROUP BY deptno;
```

---

**Oracle**

```
  SELECT r.name,
         LISTAGG(a.name SEPARATOR ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a.name)
  FROM RESOURCES r
        JOIN APPLICATIONSRESOURCES ar ON ar.resource_id = r.id
        JOIN APPLICATIONS a ON a.id = ar.app_id
  GROUP BY r.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

To be agnostic, drop back and punt.

```
Select a.name as a_name, r.name as r_name
  from ApplicationsResource ar, Applications a, Resources r
 where a.id = ar.app_id
   and r.id = ar.resource_id
 order by r.name, a.name;
```

Now user your server programming language to concatenate a_names while r_name is the same as the last time.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it in SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + Convert(nvarchar(8),DepartmentId)
FROM Table
SELECT @listStr
```

Comment: It won't do it for each GROUP BY though. For that you would need to adjust marc_s's answer in the possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query/1818036#1818036 (or see Kenneth's answer in this question)