# SQL Query to return values of a particular column concactenated with comma (,)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-concat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Create a Comma-Separated List using a SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query)

```
ItemName  | DepartmentId   
--------------------- 
Item1     | 21      
Item1     | 13
Item1     | 9
Item1     | 36
Item2     | 4
Item2     | 9
Item2     | 44
```

I need to display all the department Id's that require a particular Item using SQL Queries. The above resultset has to be displayed as follows:

```
ItemName  | DepartmentId   
--------------------- 
Item1     | 21,13,9,36      
Item2     | 4,9,44
```