# Is it possible to get the SQL single column result as a comma separated string?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I Create a Comma-Separated List using a SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query)

I am working on a web application. I need the SQL query of single column selection like

```
select 
  recordid 
from 
  device 
where 
  accountid in (1,2))
```

I need this result to be formatted comma separated string from SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Concat varchar(max)

select @Concat = CAST(recordid as varchar(10)) + coalesce(',' + @Concat , '')
 from device 
 where accountid in (1,2)

 SELECT @Concat
```

Comment: Smart way of avoid unnecessary commas...

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @result AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @result = '' -- initialize with empty string to avoid NULL result

SELECT
  @result = @result + ',' + CAST(recordid AS VARCHAR)
FROM
  device
WHERE
  accountid IN (1,2)


SELECT @result AS recordids
```

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in detail in other questions, including:

- [SQL Query to return values of a particular column concactenated with comma (,)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087684/sql-query-to-return-values-of-a-particular-column-concactenated-with-comma-c)
- [How do I Create a Comma-Separated List using a SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a custom [CLR aggregate function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91e6taax(VS.80).aspx) which can end up being more optimized than using string concatenation (especially with a really large result set).