# showing non aggregate column in a group by query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, aggregate

i have a table in SQL 2008 as

```
ID     Items
1      A
1      B
2      C
3      D
3      B
```

i would like to get the result as

```
ID    Items
1     A,B
2     C
3     B,D
```

I have used cursors but it has considerably slowed the process , can i achieve the above result using group by query or through any other way.

Thanks and Regards

Kapil

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Create a Comma-Separated List using a SQL Query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query/3087799#3087799)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a way to concatenate the results. I don't think MSSQL has a function for that, but here's a very nice tutorial on how to create a method like that: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Comment: Thanks WolpH

This thing worked for me,,,I took the  "Cursor Solution" in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
GROUP_CONCAT
```

is the function you are looking for. Something like

```
SELECT id,
       GROUP_CONCAT (DISTINCT Items ORDER BY Items SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` is a MySQL command, and as far as I am aware, it is not available in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: True, no group_concat() in SQL Server 2008. WoLpH's answer seems to be the one to go with.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, chaps. Didn't notice that bit about SQL Server 2008. APC has thoughtfully corrected the tags.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick responses. WoLpH's  comment was fruitfull. Like WoLpH i once again would like to direct users having this kind of issue to  : http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/ and check for the "cursor solution".

Best Regards
Kapil