# SQL group by -- can merge?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

In SQL we could add group by clause -- then do *sum*, *count*, or *avg* of a particular (numeric) column.
Is there a way to **"merge" / "concatenate"** particular column -- for each group?

I need this done in one SQL statement

Comment: Not in standard SQL. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I Create a Comma-Separated List using a SQL Query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query).  Commas aside, the functionality is the same.

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer in below link
http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php