# How to concat many rows into one string in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

How to concat many rows into one strings?

Query:

```
SELECT name FROM mytable;
```

Result:

```
name
----
kim
lee
park
cho
```

Just I want.

```
name
----
kim,lee,park,cho
```

Impossible?

Comment: Duplicate "MySQL : Multiple row as comma separated single row"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196371/sql-query-concatenating-results-into-one-string

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (name NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @temp (name)
VALUES ('kim'),('lee'),('park'),('cho')

SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + name
    FROM @temp
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

Output -

```
kim,lee,park,cho
```

Comment: An explanation of how this works would be helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 10):

I have been working on something similar this morning, adding the case will also work for 1 returned row. Hope this helps. Else follow the link the first comment sent you.

```
Declare @NameList VarChar(MAX) = ''    
select @NameList = 
    case when @NameList = ''
        then coalesce(Name, '')
        else @NameList + coalesce(',' + Name, '')
    end
from mytable
print @NameList
```

Ben

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
 SELECT   
name= substring((SELECT ( ', ' + Name)
                       FROM TableName t
                       FOR XML PATH( '' )
                      ), 3, 1000 )  FROM mytable tn
```