# Search through all tables for a value with a column name

Tags: sql-server

I looking to delete all the rows in selected tables where the value =.

This will give me all the tables I need to look in

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
  WHERE c.name = 'CampusID'
  ORDER BY table_name
```

But now I'm trying to search each of those tables for a value in CampusID and delete that row.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dynamic sql to generate statements

```
SELECT 
'delete from ' + t.name + ' where CampusId = ' + cast(123 as varchar(8))
  FROM sys.tables AS t
  INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
  WHERE c.name = 'FundID'
  ORDER BY t.name
```

use proper casting given your value. Then you could take all those statements and execute them all together (in a transaction) or one by one if required.

If you want to do this *all* by script, you could use this answer [How to concat many rows into one string in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102283/how-to-concat-many-rows-into-one-string-in-sql-server-2008) to join the results into one string and then use [sp_executesql](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx) to execute the script generated

Answer (score 0):

You could concatenate the code you want to run, such as:

```
SELECT  'DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + 
        ' WHERE ''CampusID'' = YourValue;' AS table_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name = 'CampusID'
ORDER BY table_name;
```

Then copy-paste the results and run it

Answer (score 0):

Threw this together quick. In this, you'll loop through all your tables/columns and use dynamic sql to delete the value which needs to be converted. I use queries like this to do what you want. I didn't test this actual query so you'll have to work it out to what you need.

```
DECLARE @loopCount      INT
DECLARE @tableName      NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @columnName     NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @strSQL         NVARCHAR(MAX);

CREATE TABLE #tempTable (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), tableName VARCHAR(128), tableCol VARCHAR(128)

INSERT INTO #tempTable(tableName, tableCol)
SELECT t.name AS table_name, c.name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name = 'CampusID'

--Set a loopCount for while loop
SET @loopCount = 1

    --Use the while loop to to loop through tables
        while ( exists(SELECT id FROM #tempTable WHERE id = @loopCount) )
            BEGIN

                --Get current record in temp table
                SELECT  @tableName      = t.tableName
                        @columnName     = t.tableCol
                FROM #tempTable t
                WHERE t.id = @loopCount
                -----------------------------------------------------------         

                SET @strSQL = 'DELETE FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE ' + @columnName + ' = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), VALUEHERE)
                EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL, N'@tableName varchar(128), @columnName varchar(128)', @tableName = @tableName, @columnName = @columnName

                DELETE FROM #tempTable WHERE id = @loopCount

                SET @loopCount = @loopCount + 1
            END


DROP TABLE #temptable
```

Comment: Certainly no need for temp tables and looping here. But as posted this isn't going to work. There is no column named id in #tempTable.

Comment: I edited and added column name. I'm giving the user another example other than a script to copy and paste. He could use this as a stored procedure or something if he had other variable columns to clean up.

Comment: Even as a stored procedure there is no need for looping. :)

Comment: I see what you're saying... just create the dynamics sql and run... SET and EXEC lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working example of using dynamic sql to accomplish this task.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = N''
    , @ValueToDelete nvarchar(25) = N'Some Value'

SELECT @SQL = @SQL + N'DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + 
        N' WHERE CampusID = ''' + @ValueToDelete + N''';'
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name = 'CampusID'

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```