# SQL FOR XML PATH returning 'illegal name character' error

Tags: sql-server, xml, correlated-subquery

I am trying to use the FOR XML PATH "trick" to create one line of text out of several rows, e.g. like in this question: [How to concat many rows into one string in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18102283/how-to-concat-many-rows-into-one-string-in-sql-server-2008)

However, SQL Server is returning an error message that says

> XML parsing: line 1, character 53, illegal name character

I am unable to figure out what is causing this error. Probably there is something in my data that is does not like... The query in question is a correlated subquery, and is resembling this:

```
(select my_text_field as [text()] 
  from child_table 
  where foreign_key = master_table.id 
  order by some_sequence 
  for xml path ('')) as comment
```

The sheer magnitude of the data involved makes it hard to manually look through the fields for oddities.

Any hints as to how I could resolve this? I was under the impression that FOR XML PATH should be able to escape illegal characters by itself, but maybe not..?

Comment: That isn't what the accepted answer in the linked question is doing though? What is the character in position 53?

Comment: @Larnu As far as I understand the question I linked, it does not address this problem. I am not sure what is in position 53 - the query runs for some 10 minutes before coming up with this error.

Comment: Try using `TYPE` and `value` as the answer does; does that solve the problem? (You'll probably want to remove the alias is the subquery too.)

Comment: can you post some of your sample input data.

Comment: it might be something in your string which is not accepted in `xml` format.

Comment: See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207371/please-explain-what-does-for-xml-path-type-value-nvarcharmax) for a better technique.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? If it's 2017 or newer, STRING_AGG is worth looking into.

Comment: We're on 2016, but perhaps it might be possible to upgrade; thanks!

Comment: @DarkRob No, this is medical data, which for obvious reasons I cannot post.

Comment: @Eyvind: have you tried my posted solution, if it is not working then kindly post the error of that query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    SELECT STUFF((SELECT N',' + my_text_field 
      FROM child_table 
      where foreign_key = master_table.id 
      order by some_sequence  
      FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)')
    ,1, 1, N'');
```