# SQL How to add values of a select statement to a varchar

Tags: sql

I'm writing a function that returns the names of a child table's one column's values in one varchar.

The relation is: 
I have a parent table called `Activity`.
And a child table in N-1 relation with table `Activity`, called `ActivityObjective`.
And a third table where I keep the names of the objectives, called `Objective`.

This is the query that I make. This returns the names of the objectives of a specific `Activity` with `ActivityID = @ActivityID`

```
SELECT      o.ObjectiveName      
FROM        Activity a    
INNER JOIN  ActivityObjective ao ON a.ActivityID = ao.ActivityID      
INNER JOIN  Objective o ON o.ObjectiveID = ao.ObjectiveID     
WHERE       a.ActivityID = @ActivityID
```

This returns something like:

```
    ObjectiveName
|-------------------|
    objName1
    objName2
    objName3
```

My aim is no have a varchar "objName1, objName2, objName3". I cannot create a temp table because I'm working in a function.

Comment: see this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196371/sql-query-concatenating-results-into-one-string

Comment: Google for [sqlserver group_concat](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=sqlserver+group_concat).  Be the 1.000.000th developer to wonder why Microsoft makes this so hard.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust the following to match what you specifically wanted, but this is a start:

```
Select  substring((
    SELECT (', ' +  o.ObjectiveName)
    FROM        Activity a    
    INNER JOIN  ActivityObjective ao ON a.ActivityID = ao.ActivityID      
    INNER JOIN  Objective o ON o.ObjectiveID = ao.ObjectiveID     
    WHERE       a.ActivityID = @ActivityID
    FOR XML PATH( '' )
), 3, 1000 )
```