# How to pivot unknown number of columns & no aggregate in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, pivot

I have query which returns clients loans with associated collateral names like below (1)
but I want to have only one distinct loan number in a row and collateral names aside like on other example (2). Been playing with pivoting but cannot figure it out because I don't have aggregate column and I don't know how many loan numbers I will get neither how many collateral each loan may have. How to do that??? Possible in SQL Server 2012?

thanks

(1)

```
loanid|name  |Address |
1     |John  |New York|
1     |Carl  |New York|
1     |Henry |Boston  |
2     |Robert|Chicago |
3     |Joanne|LA      |
3     |Chris |LA      |
```

(2) I need something like this

```
loanid|name  |address  |name |address |name|address|
1     |Jonh  |New York |Carl |New York|Henry|Boston|
2     |Robert|Chicago  |
3     |Joanne|LA       |Chris|LA|
```

Comment: Do each of your `name`/`address`s need to be separate columns of can they be a comma separated list in one column? Also what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Brad, I have mentioned it - SQL Server 2012.  Name/address could be comma separated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196371/sql-query-concatenating-results-into-one-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (loanid INT,name VARCHAR(20),[Address] VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1,'John','New York'),(1,'Carl','New York'),(1,'Henry','Boston'),
(2,'Robert','Chicago'),(3,'Joanne','LA'),(3,'Chris','LA')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  loanid
       ,ISNULL(name1, '')    AS name1
       ,ISNULL(Address1, '') AS Address1
       ,ISNULL(name2, '')    AS name2
       ,ISNULL(Address2, '') AS Address2
       ,ISNULL(name3, '')    AS name3
       ,ISNULL(Address3, '') AS Address3
FROM (
SELECT loanid
      ,'name' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loanid ORDER BY loanid)  AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS Cols
      , name AS Vals
FROM @TABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT loanid
      ,'Address' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loanid ORDER BY loanid)  AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
      , [Address] 
FROM @TABLE ) t
 PIVOT (MAX(Vals)
        FOR Cols 
        IN (name1, Address1,name2,Address2,name3,Address3)
        )P
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════╦════════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════════╗
║ loanid ║ name1  ║ Address1 ║ name2 ║ Address2 ║ name3 ║ Address3 ║
╠════════╬════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════════╣
║      1 ║ John   ║ New York ║ Carl  ║ New York ║ Henry ║ Boston   ║
║      2 ║ Robert ║ Chicago  ║       ║          ║       ║          ║
║      3 ║ Joanne ║ LA       ║ Chris ║ LA       ║       ║          ║
╚════════╩════════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════════╝
```

**Update for Dynamic Columns**

```
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Cols =  STUFF((
                    SELECT DISTINCT ', ' +  QUOTENAME(Cols)
                    FROM (
                    SELECT loanid
                          ,'name' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loanid ORDER BY loanid)  AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS Cols
                          , name AS Vals
                    FROM @TABLE
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT loanid
                          ,'Address' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY loanid ORDER BY loanid)  AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
                          , [Address] 
                    FROM @TABLE ) t
                    GROUP BY QUOTENAME(Cols)
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')


DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql  = 'SELECT ' + @Cols +   '
            FROM (
            SELECT loanid
                  ,''name'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                            (PARTITION BY loanid ORDER BY loanid)  AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS Cols
                  , name AS Vals
            FROM @TABLE
            UNION ALL
            SELECT loanid
                  ,''Address'' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                                (PARTITION BY loanid ORDER BY loanid)  AS NVARCHAR(10)) 
                  , [Address] 
            FROM @TABLE ) t
             PIVOT (MAX(Vals)
                    FOR Cols 
                    IN (' + @Cols + ')
                    )P'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
```

*Note*

This wouldnt work with the given sample data in my answer, as it uses a table variable and it is not visible to dynamic sql since it has it own scope. but this solution will work on a normal sql server table.

Also the order in which columns are selected will be slightly different.

Comment: This works well for 3 columns but it would have to be build up dynamically to truly be useful for an "unknown number of columns"

Comment: Thats not that hard either let me pull that out for you :)

Comment: @Brad you had to ask me this didnt you, have a look now pal the second solution is for dynamic number of columns.

Comment: +1 Very nice answer. It works for me! (not my question though :) )

Comment: If you really want to learn some cool techniques for pivot, look up a user called Bluefeet, go through that user's answers to questions and you will learn a lot. :)

Comment: I've seen Bluefeet :) he's very good at turning tables on their side!

Comment: the user is She not a he :), and I wasnt good at all with pivot queries but I have learnt a lot by just going through her answers to pivot question. She's a top pivot expert :)

Comment: oh nice, did not know that!

Answer (score 15):

While [M.Ali's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22773815/426671) will get you the result, since you are using SQL Server 2012  I would unpivot the `name` and `address` columns slightly different to get the final result.

Since you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use `CROSS APPLY` with `VALUES` to unpivot these multiple columns into multiple rows.  But before you do that, I would use `row_number()` to get the total number of new columns you will have.

The code to "UNPIVOT" the data using CROSS APPLY looks like:

```
select d.loanid, 
  col = c.col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
  c.value
from
(
  select loanid, name, address,
    row_number() over(partition by loanid
                      order by loanid) seq
  from yourtable
) d
cross apply
(
  values
    ('name', name),
    ('address', address)
) c(col, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e3d6/3/0). This is going to get your data into a format similar to:

```
| LOANID |      COL |    VALUE |
|--------|----------|----------|
|      1 |    name1 |     John |
|      1 | address1 | New York |
|      1 |    name2 |     Carl |
|      1 | address2 | New York |
|      1 |    name3 |    Henry |
|      1 | address3 |   Boston |
```

You now have a single column `COL` with all of your new column names and the values associated are also in a single column.  The new column names now have a number at the end  (1, 2, 3, etc) based on how many total entries you have per `loanid`.  Now you can apply PIVOT:

```
select loanid,
  name1, address1, name2, address2,
  name3, address3
from
(
  select d.loanid, 
    col = c.col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
    c.value
  from
  (
    select loanid, name, address,
      row_number() over(partition by loanid
                        order by loanid) seq
    from yourtable
  ) d
  cross apply
  (
    values
      ('name', name),
      ('address', address)
  ) c(col, value)
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (name1, address1, name2, address2,
              name3, address3)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e3d6/5/0). Finally if you don't know how many pairs of `Name` and `Address` you will have then you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col+cast(seq as varchar(10))) 
                    from 
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by loanid
                                                order by loanid) seq
                      from yourtable
                    ) d
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'Name', 1 union all
                      select 'Address', 2
                    ) c (col, so)
                    group by seq, col, so
                    order by seq, so
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT loanid,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select d.loanid, 
                col = c.col + cast(seq as varchar(10)),
                c.value
              from
              (
                select loanid, name, address,
                  row_number() over(partition by loanid
                                    order by loanid) seq
                from yourtable
              ) d
              cross apply
              (
                values
                  (''name'', name),
                  (''address'', address)
              ) c(col, value)
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/709c7/2/0). Both versions give a result:

```
| LOANID |  NAME1 | ADDRESS1 |  NAME2 | ADDRESS2 |  NAME3 | ADDRESS3 |
|--------|--------|----------|--------|----------|--------|----------|
|      1 |   John | New York |   Carl | New York |  Henry |   Boston |
|      2 | Robert |  Chicago | (null) |   (null) | (null) |   (null) |
|      3 | Joanne |       LA |  Chris |       LA | (null) |   (null) |
```

Comment: thanks but it looks too complicated. Will check these Cross Apply though.

Comment: @ZuluZ two problems. 1. Too complicated for what? I'm assuming this is short for TLDR which is very sad. 2:How complicated can it be someone has already done all the work for you as well as some very detailed explanation as to why this works.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       loanid
      ,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + name +' ('+address+')'
              FROM table a 
              WHERE a.loanid = b.loanid
              FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

FROM table  b
```

This would put

```
loanid | name(address)
1      | name (address),name2 (address2),name3........
2      | name (address),name2 (address2),name3........
3      | name (address),name2 (address2),name3........
```