# Split Rows data to Columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following data

```
Date            Value
---------------------
2014-01-01        20
2014-01-02        18
2014-01-03        06
2014-02-01        22
2014-02-02        162
2014-02-03        16
```

Here i have first 3 dates data of 2 months. I have get the output as

```
Date  Jan 2014  Feb 2014
-------------------------
 01    20          06
 02    18          162
 03    06          16
```

Comment: It's called a cross tab or pivot query

Comment: which muppet upvoted a question that shows no attempt?

Comment: hi, i tried pivot but pivot can give individual date tranpose. I dont need to transpose each data. Just take the second month value as new column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE([Date] DATE,Value INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('2014-01-01',20)  ,('2014-01-02',18),
('2014-01-03',06)  ,('2014-02-01',22),
('2014-02-02',162) ,('2014-02-03',16)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DAY([Date]) AS [Date]
      ,LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,[Date]), 3)
       + ' ' + CAST(YEAR([Date]) AS NVARCHAR(4)) Mon_YYYY
      , Value
FROM @TABLE ) t
PIVOT (SUM(Value)
       FOR Mon_YYYY
       IN ([Jan 2014],[Feb 2014])
       )P
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ Date ║ Jan 2014 ║ Feb 2014 ║
╠══════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║    1 ║       20 ║       22 ║
║    2 ║       18 ║      162 ║
║    3 ║        6 ║       16 ║
╚══════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

You will need to use Dynamic sql to unpivot the actual data as there can be many values in a column and this solution isnt really practical for real life problems but at least it gives you some idea how to go about it. See this [`How to pivot unknown number of columns & no aggregate in SQL Server?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772481/how-to-pivot-unknown-number-of-columns-no-aggregate-in-sql-server/22773815#22773815) to learn how to dynamically pivot rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT` as below

```
declare @t table (sdate date,val int)
insert into @t values('2014-01-01',        20)
insert into @t values('2014-01-02',        18)
insert into @t values('2014-01-03',        06)
insert into @t values('2014-02-01',        22)
insert into @t values('2014-02-02',        162)
insert into @t values('2014-02-03',        16)

select * from 
(
select datepart(d,sdate) sday,DATENAME(MONTH, sdate)+' '+cast(datepart(YYYY,sdate) as varchar) yearMonth,val from @t
) t
pivot 
(
sum(val)
FOR YearMonth IN ([January 2014],[February 2014])
) AS PivotTable;
```

and this is the result

```
sday January 2014 February 2014
1        20       22
2        18       162
3        6        16
```