# SQL combine multiple rows into 1 row

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to take rows with the same ID and return them on the same row. My data looks like the follow:

```
ID  Fruit
1   Banana
1   Apple
1   Grapefruit
2   Cherry
2   Blueberry
3   Lime
3   Pear
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
ID  Fruit   Fruit1  Fruit2
1   Banana  Apple   Grapefruit
2   Cherry  Blueberry   NULL
```

I have tried this as a query, but I don't seem to be having much luck:

```
SELECT a.[ID],a.[Fruit],b.[Fruit]
FROM [test].[dbo].[Fruit] a
JOIN [test].[dbo].[Fruit] b
ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE a.FRUIT <> b.FRUIT
```

Can anybody help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pivot unknown number of columns & no aggregate in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772481/how-to-pivot-unknown-number-of-columns-no-aggregate-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combination of a windowing function like `row_number` and then some conditional aggregation using a `CASE` expression with `MAX()` to get the result that you want:

```
select 
  Id,
  Fruit = max(case when rn = 1 then Fruit end),
  Fruit1 = max(case when rn = 2 then Fruit end),
  Fruit2 = max(case when rn = 3 then Fruit end)
from
(
  select 
    Id, 
    Fruit,
    rn = row_number() over(partition by Id order by Id)
  from [test].[dbo].[Fruit]
) d
group by Id;
```

See a [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/678085). The `row_number()` function creates a unique number for each `id`, then using this number along with `CASE` and `MAX` you will convert your rows of data into columns.

Comment: This worked well and was simple enough for me to grasp easily, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the fruit count is not fixed, you can you use dynamic script:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
CREATE TABLE #t(ID INT,Fruit VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #t(ID,Fruit)
SELECT 1,'Banana' UNION
SELECT 1,'Apple' UNION
SELECT 1,'Grapefruit' UNION
SELECT 2,'Cherry' UNION
SELECT 2,'Blueberry' UNION
SELECT 3,'Lime' UNION
SELECT 3,'Pear'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max),@cols VARCHAR(max)
SELECT @cols=ISNULL(@cols+',','')+t.col FROM (
   SELECT *,'Fruit'+LTRIM(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY(SELECT 1) )) AS col FROM #t AS t
) AS t GROUP BY t.col




SET @sql='
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT *,''Fruit''+LTRIM(ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY(SELECT 1) )) AS col FROM #t AS t
) AS t  PIVOT(MAX(Fruit) FOR col in ('+@cols+')) p
'
PRINT @sql
EXEC(@sql)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
```

```
ID          Fruit1     Fruit2     Fruit3
----------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1           Apple      Banana     Grapefruit
2           Blueberry  Cherry     NULL
3           Lime       Pear       NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivot to do this as below:

```
Select Id, [0] as Fruit, [1] as [Fruit1], [2] as [Fruit2] from (
    Select *, RowN = Row_Number() over (partition by Id order by Fruit) - 1 from yourtable )
pivot ( max(Fruit) for RowN in ([0], [1],[2]) ) p
```