# Get SQL Server's constraints list without redundancy

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, concatenation

With this query I get the list of all my database's `CHECK`, `FOREIGN_KEY`, `PRIMARY_KEY` and `UNIQUE_KEY` constraints.

```
SELECT 
    o.object_id as ID, o.name AS Name, 
    OBJECT_NAME(o.parent_object_id) AS TableName, 
    o.type_desc AS TypeName, 
    cs.COLUMN_NAME as ColumnName
FROM 
    sys.objects o 
LEFT JOIN 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cs ON o.name = cs.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
WHERE 
    o.type = 'C' or o.type = 'F' or o.type = 'PK' or o.type = 'UQ'
```

However, there are some of them with many 'ColumnName' and I want to concat this.

For example :

```
  'PK_ENTITE_SIGN_DOSSIER_ID_DOSSIER_ID_ENTITE_ID_GROUPE_SIGN_ID_PERSONNE_ID_SCHEMA'
```

is a `PRIMARY_KEY` on table `ENTITE_SIGN_DOSSIER` and contains `ID_DOSSIER`, `ID_ENTITE`, `ID_GROUPE_SIGN`, `ID_PERSONNE` and `ID_SCHEMA` (5 columns) and in this case, my query return 5 lines for this constraint.

How can I concat those columns name on the query's result please ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: A simple search in your favorite search engine on "stackoverflow sql server concatenate row values" will yield many examples on how to concatenate the column names. First two examples I found should shed some light on this: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874966/concatenate-row-values-t-sql) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196371/sql-query-concatenating-results-into-one-string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is standard `xml` and `stuff` function trick:

```
SELECT  o.object_id AS ID ,
        o.name AS Name ,
        OBJECT_NAME(o.parent_object_id) AS TableName ,
        o.type_desc AS TypeName ,
        ca.ColumnName
FROM    sys.objects o
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + cs.COLUMN_NAME
                                        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE cs
                                        WHERE   o.name = cs.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                      FOR
                                        XML PATH('')
                                      ), 1, 2, '') AS ColumnName
                    ) ca
WHERE   o.type = 'C'
        OR o.type = 'F'
        OR o.type = 'PK'
        OR o.type = 'UQ'
ORDER BY ID
```