# TSQL: How do I join a subsequence result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have these tables:

```
Table  Persons:
ID     Name
1      John

Table  Groups:
ID     Group
1      Admin
2      Printer
3      Server

Table PersonsAndGroups:
ID     person_ID    group_ID
1      1            1
2      1            2
3      1            3
```

Now I want a view that will give me this result:

```
PersonID PersonName Groups
1        John       Admin, Printer, Server
```

I though of somehing like...

```
SELECT ID AS PersonID, Name AS PersonName, (SELECT ????) FROM Persons
```

... but I can't figure out the "subquery".

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5196474/1266737

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/440f8a/1