# Multiple Rows to single column using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert my found data to a single column

My data is

```
Id
------
3
4
5
```

that record I want to this format

```
id
=======
3,4,5
```

Comment: Google  "SQL Server string aggregation"

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
 SELECT STUFF( (SELECT ',' + Id
                                 FROM My_Table
                                 ORDER BY Id
                                 FOR XML PATH('')), 
                                1, 1, '')
```

**[Original_Post_Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196371/sql-query-concatenating-results-into-one-string)**

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT @str = coalesce(@str + ',', '') + a.[Your Column]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [Your Column]
    FROM [your Table]
    ) a

SELECT @str
```