# Create list of dates, a month apart, starting from current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a simple select query (not using a table) to just return a list of dates, 1 month apart.  The output should looke something like this, (assuming GetDate() = '2011-07-05 11:59:000' and I wanted between NOW() and NOW()+4 months

```
Date
2011-07-05 11:59:000
2011-08-05 11:59:000
2011-09-05 11:59:000
2011-10-05 11:59:000
2011-11-05 11:59:000
```

The part that's killing me is calculating the next year, for example if i run this query in Nov, the months should be listed as 11, 12, 1, 2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JNK's answer, just reworked to give you each date in a row:

```
SELECT GETDATE() 'Date'
UNION
SELECT DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()) 'Date'
UNION
SELECT DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE()) 'Date'
UNION
SELECT DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE()) 'Date'
UNION
SELECT DATEADD(month, 4, GETDATE()) 'Date'
```

Had to do something like this just this morning!

Comment: Question is: Do you know of a shorter way to do this, other than a bunch of `UNION`s?

Comment: Works perfect Ryan, thanks!  A short way would be nice, but this works.  Thanks!

Comment: @Russ You could use a recursive CTE for this as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can use recursive CTE and need not string UNIONs together if the requirement is not fixed as below:

```
 ;with MonthlyCalendar as (
 select cast(getdate() as datetime) as dt
 union all
 select dateadd(mm, 1, dt)
 from MonthlyCalendar
) 
select top 5 dt as [Date] from MonthlyCalendar
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

When it comes to performance and you have the need for only 4 months above UNION is far superior than recursive option.

Comment: Your script is just fine, i was a bit worried because you had changed the maxrecursion. It is more or less the same. So I deleted mine and gave you credit. You dont need "order by" in this case.

Comment: I wasnt sure as I read somewhere that whenever recursion is used to make sure of the order-by, however thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to handle these small (one off) situations by looping through the data and building the list based on the current (or target) date:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#dates') is not null drop table #dates
select dateadd(MINUTE, -1, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(DD, 1, getdate()), 111)) result into #dates

declare @current datetime
select @current = result from #dates

while not exists (select * from #dates where result = dateadd(month, 4, @current))
  begin
    insert into #dates
    select dateadd(month, 1, max(result)) from #dates
  end

select * from #dates order by result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GETDATE(),
       DATEADD(month, 1, GETDATE()),    
       DATEADD(month, 2, GETDATE()),
       DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE()),
       DATEADD(month, 4, GETDATE())
```

`DATEADD` takes care of all  that year consideration logic for you, and leap years and such too.

Obviously this returns a list of columns.  See Ryan's answer for the row solution!

Comment: +1 but quickly gets unwieldy if you want some larger number of dates.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
declare @LastLimit as int
set @LastLimit = 4
SET @intFlag = 0
WHILE (@intFlag <@LastLimit)
BEGIN
select DATEADD(month, @intFlag, GETDATE())  
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic script to build a calendar set.
A good example can be found here: 
http://blog.namwarrizvi.com/?p=139

In that example you would just replaced the `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` to use months instead of days.

Comment: Please note the first sentence of the OP: I'm looking for a simple select query **(not using a table)**

Comment: Note that this does not `INSERT` into anything, "calendar table" is just common phrasing for what he's after. I'll edit my answer to say "Calendar set" because, without a corresponding `INSERT` that's precisely what this is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic elegant solution on the problem here: [Get usernames logged in on day by day basis from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441795/get-usernames-logged-in-on-day-by-day-basis-from-database/6442104#6442104)

Of course, it will require adjustments, but the principle is great.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Oracle, you can easily create a list of dates using CONNECT BY.
For example, if you want all the months between '2000-12-31' and today:

```
select add_months(date '2000-12-31',level) dates
from dual 
connect by level <=  months_between(sysdate, date '2000-12-31');
```

The function used to obtain the number of months, here `months_between`, can change between different SQL versions (e.g. in SQL Server it should be `datediff()`).

Answer (score -1):

It's often useful to keep a table of incrementing values, as large as you need it to be:

```
create table sequence ( value int not null primary key clustered )
insert sequence values(0)
insert sequence values(1)
insert sequence values(2)
insert sequence values(3)
. . .
insert sequence values(n)
```

With such a table, producing a list of any size is trivial. This will give you 36 date/time values a month apart, starting with the current date/time.

```
select top 36
       dtValue = dateadd( month , sequence.value , date(current_timestamp) )
from dbo.sequence
order by sequence.value
```