# Mysql - Wordpress: list custom posts with more than one metadata value

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join, foreign-keys, custom-fields

In wordpress, custom posts are held in the `wp_posts` table, and their ID is referenced in another table `wp_meta` with the following columns `post_id, meta_key, meta_value`

Let's say I have a recipe called `pudding` in `wp_posts`, and in `wp_meta` I have 3 `meta_keys: "time_for_preparation", "ingredients", "difficulty"`

How do I write a mysql query that returns me a single row with the 3 meta_keys?

If I do an inner join I'll just see 3 sets of "pudding", each with the same `wp_posts` data and ONE different meta_key

What I want is a single row of `pudding` with an array of meta_keys

can that be done?

Comment: you need output like this pudding "time_for_preparation, ingredients,difficulty"

Comment: do you need meta_keys comma seprated in one column

Comment: comma separated would be good, but ideally I need columns with the meta_key "title" holding the meta_value "value"...like if everything was in the wp_posts table in a single row

Answer (score 0):

```
create table wp_post
( 
 id int identity(1,1),
 name nvarchar(200) 
)


create table wp_meta
(
  id int identity(1,1),
   postid int,
  metaname nvarchar(200)
)



insert into wp_post select 'Apple'

insert into wp_meta select 1,'red'

select * from wp_post
select  * from wp_meta


select *
 ,stuff((select  ', ' +metaname from wp_meta where postid=w.id for xml path('')), 1, 1,' ')
 from wp_post as w
```

this is all done by me in MS SQL Server

for changing this into you can see this post which have for MYSql [how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query)

**Edited**

as i dont have mysql but i tried to convert this by using the url which i have suggested you so i think this will be in mysql like below

```
SELECT w.name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(m.meta_key, ',')
    FROM wp_post w
    JOIN wp_meta m ON m.post_id= w.id    
GROUP BY w.name
```

Comment: It's more like this:
 

    create table wp_post
    ( 
     id int identity(1,1),
     name nvarchar(200) 
    )
    
    
    create table wp_meta
    (
      id int identity(1,1),
       postid int,
    metakey nvarchar(200)
      metaname nvarchar(200)
    )
    
    insert into wp_post select 'Apple'
    
    insert into wp_meta select 1,'color','red'
    insert into wp_meta select 1,'brand','del monte'
    insert into wp_meta select 1,'weight','1oz'

And I want to be returned a set of data like

name=Apple, color=red, brand=del monte,weight=1oz



Thanks for helping!

Comment: what you get by this in MYSQl SELECT w.name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(m.meta_key, ',')
    FROM wp_post w
    JOIN wp_meta m ON m.post_id= w.id    
GROUP BY w.name