# Need unique value of a column while combining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting two columns from two different tables using sql server 2005.. For that I used the following query..

```
SELECT [MHD].JobPostingId,
       [C].CandidateName 
  FROM 
       Candidate as C RIGHT JOIN MemberHiringDetails MHD 
                      ON [MHD].MemberId=[C].Id
```

It returns the following data:

```
JobPostingId  CandidateName
60            aaa
60            bbb
63            aaa
```

NULL means, that candidate is erased from that table.. But I need output as follows:

```
JobPostingId  CandidateName
60            aaa, bbb
63            aaa
```

How to do this..? If it need stored procedure means, ok.. All I need is solution..

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Mahmoud Gamal, duplicate.
Extracted from another post and changed for your tables:

```
SELECT C.name,
       STUFF((SELECT ','+ C.CandidateName
               FROM Candidate C
              WHERE C.Id = MHD.MemberId
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')
 FROM MemberHiringDetails MHD
```

thx to OMG Ponies in post:
[How do I Create a Comma-Separated List using a SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query)