# Find duplicates in SQL table, list multiple instances

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to list the multiple instances of tbldoc.[docid] from tbldoc where tbldoc.[filename] occurs more than once, id like them seperated by comma and grouped by [filename]

```
this code works great to find duplicates:
SELECT cast([filename] as varchar(max)),  
 COUNT(cast([filename] as varchar(max))) 
FROM tbldoc
GROUP BY cast([filename] as varchar(max))
HAVING ( COUNT(cast([filename] as varchar(max))) > 1 )
```

but when i try adding [docid] i get an error:

> Column 'tbldoc.DocID' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

this is what i am trying:

```
SELECT [docid], cast([filename] as varchar(max)),  
 COUNT(cast([filename] as varchar(max))) 
FROM tbldoc
GROUP BY cast([filename] as varchar(max))
HAVING ( COUNT(cast([filename] as varchar(max))) > 1 )
```

I have no idea how to get all of the [docid]s to list seperated by commas, I'm a a pretty new user when it comes to sql.

this is the output i would like to see:

> [docids]|[filemame]|[instances]
>
> 12345,12346| excelfile.xls | 3

Thanks ahead of time for the help guys/gals! =)

Comment: How are there 3 instances of `excelfile.xls` but only 2 `docids`? Are there multiple entries with the same `docid`?

Comment: This question may help you get that comma delimited list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query

Comment: Goat, that was just a typed out example... a poor one at that, it should have showed 2 instances.

Answer (score 0):

Iyosha,

You need to join your first result set back to your full table to get the DocIDs.  I'll take the CAST() as read to save some typing.

```
;with CountedFiles as
(
    SELECT
        filename,  
        COUNT(filename) as Total
    FROM tbldoc
    GROUP BY filename
    HAVING COUNT(filename) > 1
)
select
    cf.filename,
    cf.Total,
    td.DocID
from CountedFiles as cf
inner join tbldoc at td
    on td.filename = cf.filename;
```

This will return one DocId, one filename and the count per row. You can then follow Adam's link to turn this into a comma list.