# Concatenate columns in Pivot View

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, concatenation, sql-server-group-concat

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(ACT_DESC)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ACT_DESC FROM tpc) AS desc

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT MDCODE, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM tpc
    PIVOT(MAX(ACTUAL_DATE) 
          FOR tpcIN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

This query displays:

```
MDCODE | sample1 | sample2
--------------------------
123    | 1/2014  | 
123    |         | 2/2014
123    |         | 3/2014
```

What I want is this:

```
MDCODE | sample1 | sample2
--------------------------
123    | 1/2014  | 2/2014,3/2014
```

Does anyone have an idea how to concat the column data? Any tips?

This is the table where i get the data:

```
   mdcode | act_desc | actual_date
   --------------------------
   1234   | sample1  | 1/2014
   1234   | sample2  | 2/2014
   1234   | sample2  | 3/2014
```

the actual_date is datetime

Comment: Why don't you show what data looks like in the tables you are pulling data out of so that we can think of how to reach the conclusion that you have described?

Comment: **First tip**: turn **OFF** your CAPS LOCK! Writing in ALL CAPS is annoying, it's really hard to read, it's considered **SHOUTING** at people - those people who might be able to help you. It's rude - just **don't do it!**

Comment: sorry i am new here i dont the does and dont thank you for your concenrn

Comment: @Ahmad i posted the table where i got the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would skip the PIVOT altogether  and just use FOR XML_PATH, like this:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @DynamicPivotQuery= ISNULL(@DynamicPivotQuery + ',','select mdcode,') 
       + 'stuff((select '',''+actual_date from tpc where mdcode=t.mdcode and act_desc = ''' + ACT_DESC + ''' for xml path(''''),type).value(''.'',''varchar(max)''),1,1,'''') '
       + QUOTENAME(ACT_DESC)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ACT_DESC FROM tpc) AS des

select @DynamicPivotQuery = @DynamicPivotQuery + 'from tpc t group by mdcode'
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

The dynamic query generates a query like this:

```
select mdcode,
        stuff(
              (
                select ','+actual_date
                from tpc where mdcode=t.mdcode and act_desc = 'sample1'
                for xml path(''),type
              ).value('.','varchar(max)')
              ,1,1,'') sample1,
        stuff(
              (
                select ','+actual_date
                from tpc where mdcode=t.mdcode and act_desc = 'sample2'
                for xml path(''),type
              ).value('.','varchar(max)')
              ,1,1,'') sample2
from tpc t
group by mdcode;
```

The [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/202d7/7) demonstrates the static query and the dynamic one

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, the type of comma separated output is achieved with "for xml path", but is also usually associated with stuff()

Optionally via "cross apply" although it doesn't have to be done that way.

I would approach it like this. Don't use `pivot` now, just reduce MDCODE & ACT_DESC by distinct or group by, then using cross apply concatenate the string of "dates". If they really are dates then you will need to convert them to varchar e.g. convert(varchar,actual_date,112)

```
| MDCODE | ACT_DESC |  ACTUAL_DATES |
|--------|----------|---------------|
|   1234 |  sample1 |        1/2014 |
|   1234 |  sample2 | 2/2014,3/2014 |
```

produced by:

```
SELECT
      d.mdcode
    , d.act_desc
    , ca1.actual_dates
FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                  [mdcode]
                , [act_desc]
            FROM Table1
      ) d
      CROSS APPLY (
                  SELECT
                        STUFF((
                              SELECT
                                    ',' + a.actual_date
                              FROM table1 a
                              WHERE a.mdcode = d.mdcode
                                  AND a.act_desc = d.act_desc --<< change here
                              ORDER BY a.actual_date
                              FOR xml PATH ('')
                        )
                        , 1, 1, '')
            ) AS ca1 (actual_dates)
;
```

By the way STUFF() is used to remove the first comma from the concatenation, that is its only role. CROSS APPLY is arguably better than using a correlated subquery in the select clause, because it is performed before that clause as part of the from clause. As I said earlier its optional but I prefer it.

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a24ba/4
& also see [these samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query)

Comment: thanks,but how can i combine it with pivoting the table

Comment: you don't need the pivot at all, it will just complicate things unnecessarily, please give me some time.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'convert'. a.convert(varchar,actual_date,112) its error when i convert it

Comment: convert(varchar,a.actual_date,112)  don't put the alias at the front of convert, the alias attaches to the field name

Comment: appears the solution below meets your needs

Comment: why is data added the output should be                              '>| MDCODE | ACT_DESC |         ACTUAL_DATES |'
'>|--------|----------|----------------------|'
'>|   1234 |  sample1 | 1/2014               |'
'>|   1234 |  sample2 | 1/2014,2/2014,3/2014 |'

Comment: the query may need one extra line look for `--<< change here` in the query above