# Colon Separated List in SQL Server (Like LISTAGG)

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am looking to produce an concatenated string in SQL Server from the following data that looks like the results below:

```
Table A                   |     Table B:
                          |   
LOC      Acct    ID       |   ID      SN
ATL      60      1        |   1       100A
ATL      60      2        |   2       300B
DAL      61      3        |   3       600X
DAL      61      4        |   4       500H
```

Results:

```
LOC     Acct      SN
ATL     60        100A:300B
DAL     61        600X:500H
```

I have looked at using the STUFF function  & this article [How do I Create a Comma-Separated List using a SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query), but I don't seem to be working it out properly.

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is what I have tried & the results are all the SNs concatenated; I'm missing something:

```
      SELECT distinct 
       A2.LOC,
       A2.Acct,
       STUFF((SELECT ':'+ b.SN
               FROM TableA a
              JOIN TableB b ON b.ID = a.ID
            GROUP BY a.acct
                    , b.sn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '')  SN_List
      FROM TableA a2 



Results:

LOC      Acct       SN
ATL      60         100A:300B:500H:600X
ATL      60         100A:300B:500H:600X
DAL      61         100A:300B:500H:600X
DAL      61         100A:300B:500H:600X
```

Comment: What have you actually tried? You linked to another answer here that has the correct syntax in OMG Ponies answer. Please post the query that you attempted from that info and it will be easier to point out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need the `GROUP BY`.
2. You *do* need a `WHERE` condition in the subquery to correlate the `Acct` value from the row of the outer query with the subset of values you want to concatenate in the inner query.
3. You will need to add the `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT` in the outer query as TableA repeats those values.
4. For readability and to decrease possible odd behavior that is hard to debug, you shouldn't re-use table aliases in subqueries. If you are re-select from TableA, as opposed to using the row values from TableA of the outer query, use something like `a2` instead of the same `a` alias.

The following works as per your SqlFiddle (noted in a comment on this answer):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
  A2.LOC,
  A2.Acct,
       STUFF((SELECT ':'+ b.SN
              FROM TableA a
              INNER JOIN TableB b
                      ON b.ID = a.ID
              WHERE  a.Acct = a2.Acct
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','VARCHAR(max)'), 1, 1, '') SN_List
 FROM TableA a2
```

Comment: Actually, with those suggestions, I am still getting the same results - I modified the query & created it on SQL Fiddle.  I updated the post as well with my changes. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6170c/25

Comment: @cscratch Fixed. I have attached the query that works in your SqlFifddle.

Comment: Definitely see now why I was getting the previous results.  Thank you!