# Combine multiple rows in one row in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For example, I've 2 tables as follows-

Table: Parents

```
-------------------------
| ParentId | ParentName |
-------------------------
| 1        |      abc   |
------------------------- 
| 2        |      xyz   |
-------------------------
```

Table: Childs

```
----------------------------------
| ChildId | ChildName | ParentId |
----------------------------------
| 1       |      p    |    1     |
---------------------------------- 
| 2       |      q    |    1     |
----------------------------------
```

I would to have a Query: Parents_Childs

```
--------------------------
| ParentName | ChildName |
--------------------------
|   abc      |   p, q    | 
--------------------------
```

Is there any way to do it in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: SQL Server... GROUP BY, with STUFF?

Comment: @jarlh `STUFF`, yes, but in addition you need to trick with XML output.

Comment: This is really one of the most-asked questions. (IMHO, Microsoft should create a designated simple function for creating such results). Here is another link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query

Comment: Still, upvote from me, because the question per se is very clear.

Comment: @SQLPolice , me too. Other questions might be similar with this to some extent, but not exact. This is a precise problem. So, upvote from me also.