# SQL Server Convert Particular Column Values into comma separated String

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I have a table in Database as below :

```
Id  Name
1   Item1
1   Item2
2   Item3
1   Item4
3   Item5
```

I need output as below(3rd column is count):

```
1   Item1,Item2,Item4   3
2   Item3               1
3   Item5               1
```

How it can achieved by SQL Query ?

Comment: What database are you using? (SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Create a Comma-Separated List using a SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query)

Comment: I am using SQL Server

Comment: Hi Mudaissar, Yes It is the duplicate ,but I was not able to search the exact link for the issue

Answer (score 12):

SQL Server has `STUFF()` function which could able to help you.

```
SELECT t.Id,
       Name = STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ','+Name 
                      FROM table 
                      WHERE Id = t.Id 
                      FOR XML PATH('')
                     ), 1, 1, ''
                   ) 
FROM table t
GROUP BY t.Id;
```

Comment: STUFF Worked for me..Thanx

Comment: The [`STUFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function has nothing to do with rows to column. It just helps in manipulating the string. It's [`FOR XML`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) clause that makes this magic. See [How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212160/1369235)

Answer (score 7):

SQL Server 2017 has introduced a much easier way to achieve this using `STRING_AGG(expression, separator)`.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(T.Name, ', ') FROM MyTable T where MyColumnID = 78
```

You could even play around with formatting in other ways like this one:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(T.MyColumnID,' - ',T.Name), ', ') FROM MyTable T where MyColumnID = 78
```

More info in this blog I found about it: https://database.guide/the-sql-server-equivalent-to-group_concat/