# How to compare column values in cfscript?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfquery, cfloop

I would like to loop over query and compare column values. Here is example of CFML code:

```
<cfquery name="qryUserPerm" datasource="#Application.dsn#">
    SELECT AccessType, AccessLevel, State, City, Building
    FROM Permissions
    WHERE AccountID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#trim(session.AccountID)#">
</cfquery>

<cfset local.permissionType = "">
<cfset local.permissionLevel = "">
<cfset local.permissionList = "">

<cfif qryUserPerm.AccessLevel EQ "S">
     <cfset local.permissionType = qryUserPerm.AccessType>
     <cfset local.permissionLevel = qryUserPerm.AccessLevel>
     <cfset local.permissionList = qryUserPerm.State>
<cfelseif qryUserPerm.AccessLevel EQ "C">
     <cfset local.permissionType = qryUserPerm.AccessType>
     <cfset local.permissionLevel = qryUserPerm.AccessLevel>
     <cfset local.permissionList = ListRemoveDuplicates(ValueList(permissionList,qryUserPerm.City))>
<cfelseif qryUserPerm.AccessLevel EQ "B">
     <cfset local.permissionType = qryUserPerm.AccessType>
     <cfset local.permissionLevel = qryUserPerm.AccessLevel>
     <cfset local.permissionList = ListRemoveDuplicates(ValueList(permissionList,qryUserPerm.Building))>
</cfif>
```

Code above should be translated to cfscript, I got this far but can't figure it out how to access column values.

```
<cfscript>
    public string function permissionList(required string AccountID) {
        local.fnResults = "";
        local.permissionList = "";

        try{
            local.qryPermissions = new Query();
            local.qryPermissions.setDatasource("#Application.dsn#");
            local.qryPermissions.setSQL("SELECT AccessType, AccessLevel, State, City, Building FROM Permissions WHERE AccountID = :AccountID");
            local.qryPermissions.addParam(name="AccountID",value="#trim(arguments.AccountID)#",cfsqltype="cf_sql_idstamp");
            local.qryRes = qryPermissions.execute();

            for ( i = 1 ; i <= qryRes.getResult().recordCount ; i++ ) {
                if(qryRes["AccessLevel"][i] EQ "S"){
                    local.permissionList = "";
                }else if(qryRes["AccessLevel"][i] EQ "S"){
                    local.permissionList = ListRemoveDuplicates(ValueList(qryRes.Agency,","));
                }else if(qryRes["AccessLevel"][i] EQ "C"){
                    local.permissionList = ListRemoveDuplicates(ValueList(qryRes.District,","));
                }else if(qryRes["AccessLevel"][i] EQ "B"){
                    local.permissionList = ListRemoveDuplicates(ValueList(qryRes.Building,","));
                }
            }

            local.fnResults = permissionList;
        }catch(any e){
            local.fnResults = e.message;
            //writeOutput(e.message);    
        }

        return fnResults;
    }

    writeOutput(permissionList(AccountID));
</cfscript>
```

If anyone can help please let me know.

Comment: If you mean assign or access values, your code is already accessing the column values here: `qryRes["AccessLevel"][i]` using the syntax `queryName["ColumnName"][RowNumber]`.  Just use that same syntax where ever else it's needed.

Comment: I have to compare `accessLevel` column value and check if it's `S` state, `C` city or `B` buildings. Based on that values will be assigned to permissionList variable. Does that make sense? Code doesn't work, I'm confused since this is the correct syntax in CFML.

Comment: Yes, the logic makes sense, but I don't follow which line(s) aren't working. (Btw, the suggestion I made on your other thread, about a CASE in the SQL would make all of this moot...)

Comment: @Ageax This is the error that I'm getting in catch block `Element AccessLevel is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.runtime.TemplateProxy. `.

Comment: (update) Oh! I think the issue is that `local.qryRes` doesn't contain a query. Confusingly calling `execute()` doesn't return a query, but `execute().getResult()` does. Try changing the assignment to `local.qryRes = qryPermissions.execute().getResult()`. Don't forget to drop the getResult() from the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From comments ...)

The issue is `local.qryRes` doesn't actually contain a query object. Confusingly, calling execute() doesn't return a query, but calling execute().getResult() does. Try changing the assignment from:

```
local.qryRes = qryPermissions.execute();
```

To:

```
local.qryRes = qryPermissions.execute().getResult();
```

---

A few other observations:

1. It is important to *local* scope ALL function variables, including your loop index `i`. Otherwise, you may get some bizarre and unpredictable results if the component is stored in a shared scope.
2. Although I don't think a loop is necessary, if you do loop, consider the simpler `for..in` syntax, instead of an indexed loop:

   ```
   for (local.row in local.qryPermissions ) {
       if (local.row.AccessType eq "S") {
           //... code here 
       }
       .... 
   }
   ```
3. Since the access fields are so closely related, I'd probably have the function return a structure containing all three keys (AccessType, AccessLevel, PermissionList) rather than having three separate functions.
4. Rather than using a loop, consider going with one of the suggestions on your other thread, 
   [Best way to store permissions for the user account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527787/best-way-to-store-permissions-for-the-user-account/51529914#51529914)

Comment: Also, if you're using CF11+, consider using the newer [QueryExecute()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/queryexecute.html) instead of `new Query()` (older component).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use :

```
local.qryPermissions = queryExecute(
        "SELECT AccessType, AccessLevel, State, City, Building
        FROM Permissions 
        WHERE AccountID = :AccountID" ,
        {AccountID={value="#trim(arguments.AccountID)#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_idstamp"}}  // Or "?" and "[value=xxx,cfsqltype=xxx]"
    ) ;
```

And then just build out your permissions pieces without the loop:

```
  local.permissionType = qryPermissions.AccessType ;
  local.permissionLevel = qryPermissions.AccessLevel ;

  switch( qryPermissions.AccessLevel ) {
    case "S" :  local.permissionList = qryPermissions.State ;
      break ;
    case "C" :  local.permissionList = ListRemoveDuplicates(ValueList(qryPermissions.City)) ;
      break ;
    case "B" :  local.permissionList = ListRemoveDuplicates(ValueList(qryPermissions.Building)) ;
      break ;
  }
```

Also see my notes on the other question about potential for unintentional, semi-related data.

Comment: OK, I _PROMISE_ that @Ageax and I aren't the same person. Nor do we share the same brain. Though it often seems that way.