# Creating a List within a Field Using CAST()

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

I am trying to create a column titled "skills" which lists each skill a given person is associated with. Essentially, I am currently receiving the following results:

```
NAME            SKILL

Person A        Programming
Person A        Web Design
Person A        SQL
Person B        Project Management
Person B        Written Communication
```

And I need to get results like this:

```
NAME            SKILL

Person A        Programming, Web Design, SQL
Person B        Project Management, Written Communication
```

This is what my SQL code currently looks like:

```
CAST((
    SELECT InterestCodeRoot.Code + ','
    FROM InterestCodeRoot
    WHERE EmployeeInterestCode.CodeIdent = InterestCodeRoot.CodeIdent
    FOR XML PATH(''))as varchar(max))
    AS [Skill ID],
```

I have also tried using STUFF() and GROUP_CONCAT() but neither alternative has worked. This is the closest I have gotten. Any advice or assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a comma-separated list using a SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Comment: You say the above didn't work. *Why* didn't it?

Comment: Your query doesn't match your tables column names. Not sure what is the question about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comma separated results in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870326/comma-separated-results-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest method is `string_agg()`, available in the more recent versions of SQL Server:

```
select name, string_agg(skill, ', ') within group (order by skill)
from InterestCodeRoot
group by name;
```