# Is this select possible in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select

Consider a table,

```
Id columnA
1  a
2  b
3  c
```

Select ColumnA from table gives the result as below,

```
columnA
   a
   b
   c
```

Is it possible to get

```
ColumnA
a,b,c
```

Comment: duplicate of [Concatenating Column Values into a Comma-Separated List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048209/concatenating-column-values-into-a-comma-separated-list) and many others. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btsql%5D+concatenate%2Bcsv

Answer (score 1):

One way is the XML PATH trick

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(
    (
    SELECT
        ',' + columnA
    FROM
        myTable
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    )
     , 2, 7999)
FROM
     foo
```

Comment: i want my result in  the result pane

Answer (score 0):

heres an article describing how to do it with a [stored procedure](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/converting-multiple-rows-into-a-csv-string) which internally uses a loop to do the concatenation.