# Sql function to append column

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql

Lets say I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name      value  
1 Ford    "some text here and there."    
2 Honda   "More Text Again"
```

How can I write a sql function that will append me the 'value' column of all of the rows. so the result would be

```
sometext here and there. More Text Again
```

also it would be nice if I can specify a separator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenating Column Values into a Comma-Separated List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048209/concatenating-column-values-into-a-comma-separated-list). Did you try searching? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=concatenate%2Bcolumn

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that does that.  In this case the separator is `,`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  AppendColumn (@ItemID int)

    RETURNS varchar (8000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @AppendedText   varchar (8000)
    SET     @AppendedText   = NULL  -- MUST be null to avoid leading comma.

    SELECT
        @AppendedText       =  COALESCE (@AppendedText + ', ', '') + value
    FROM
        YourTable
    WHERE
        ... ...
    ORDER BY
        ... ...

    RETURN @AppendedText
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat using `FOR XML PATH` if you are using 2005+:

```
SELECT Value + ','
FROM table
FOR XML PATH('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the values together in a variable, adding a separator, using a statement like this:

```
SELECT @result = @result + t.Value + @separator
FROM @test AS t;
```

As a full example:

```
--** Declare test table
DECLARE @test TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20), Value VARCHAR(50));

--** Insert test data
INSERT INTO @test (Name, Value)
SELECT 'Ford', 'some text here and there.' UNION ALL
SELECT 'Ford', 'More Text Again'

--** Declare variables
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @separator VARCHAR(3);

--** Set separator and initialize the result (important)
SET @result = '';
SET @separator = ' | ';

--** Concatente the values together separating them with @separator
SELECT @result = @result + t.Value + @separator
FROM @test AS t;

--** Return the result removing the final separator
SELECT LEFT(@result, LEN(@result)-1);
```

This uses | as the separator and will give you:

```
some text here and there. | More Text Again
```