# How to concatenate the text when group by a particular column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have a table StudentNote with three fields 'StudentID','Notes','Date'.i have the following values

[image]

Now my requirement is ,i wanted to group the above table on StudentID  and Concatenate Note and Date Fields like

[image]

How can i write a sql to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually [this is probably a better duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817985/how-do-i-create-a-comma-separated-list-using-a-sql-query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT T1.STUDENTID,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), NOTE) + ','
                     + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DATE)
              FROM   STUDENTNOTE B
              WHERE  B.STUDENTID = T1.STUDENTID
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') [NOTE]
FROM   STUDENTNOTE T1
GROUP  BY T1.STUDENTID
```

Comment: and 'AS Note' after STUFF(...) to label the column :)

Comment: Be careful about just using XML PATH without TYPE; in this case it's probably fine but data can get messed up in other scenarios. Please see [this blog post](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) for more information (also there is better syntax in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1818045/61305)). Finally, [DO NOT convert to `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).