# TSQL XML Comma delimited list

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get a comma delimited field. The structure looks very similar to the one below. I'd like to get a comma delimited list for all  nodes below.

```
DECLARE @Test XML = '

    <Order id="orderId">
      <Products>
        <Product>1</Product>
        <Product>2</Product>
        <Product>3</Product>
        <Product>4</Product>
        <Product>5</Product>
      </Products>
      <Address street="1234 City World" zip="12345" city="City" state="FL"></Address>
</Order>'

SELECT 
  @Test.value('(/Order/@id)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS OrderId,
  @Test.value('(/Order/Address/@street)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS Street,
  @Test.value('(/Order/Address/@city)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS City,
  @Test.value('(/Order/Address/@state)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS State,
  @Test.value('(/Order/Address/@zip)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS Zip,
  @Test.query('Order/Products/Product/text()') AS prods
```

I am getting those:

"orderid" for OrderId
"1234 City World" For Street
"City" For City
"FL" for State
"1245" for Zip.
"12345" for Prods.

I would like to get "1,2,3,4,5" for prods.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reach the result you expect by using this:

```
SELECT  @Test.value('(/Order/@id)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS OrderId ,
        @Test.value('(/Order/Address/@street)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS Street ,
        @Test.value('(/Order/Address/@city)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS City ,
        @Test.value('(/Order/Address/@state)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS State ,
        @Test.value('(/Order/Address/@zip)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(1000)') AS Zip ,
        ( SELECT    
            STUFF(( SELECT  ',' + Prods.Prod.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)')
                    FROM    @Test.nodes('/Order/Products/Product') AS Prods ( Prod )
                    FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '')
        ) prods
```

It's kind of confusing, but what I do is to select the Products node and convert it to a "table" of Products then I use the `FOR XML` and the `STUFF` in order to concatenate them at the same line.

The STUFF function doesn't work on older versions of SQL Server, so maybe you'll need to adapt this solution, you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1048209/2506478) in case you need.

I hope it helps.