# How do I increase whichever buffer is overflowing for a user defined function in MSSQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, jqgrid

Trying to pull back a large set of data to populate select box filters for a JQGrid table and I'm running into this overflow.

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "FormDelimitedString": 
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: The buffer is insufficient. Read or write operation failed.
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: 
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBytes.Write(Int64 offset, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offsetInBuffer, Int32 count)
   at System.Data.SqlTypes.StreamOnSqlBytes.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
   at SqlServerProject1.FormDelimitedString.Write(BinaryWriter w)
```

Here is the SQL:

```
 SELECT 
  dbo.formDelimitedString (DISTINCT v_mie_all.AREA) AS AREA, 
  dbo.formDelimitedString (DISTINCT v_mie_all.PROP_TYPE) AS PROP_TYPE, 
  dbo.formDelimitedString (DISTINCT ((SUBSTRING (v_mie_all.rp_code, 1, 4)))) AS REC_TYPE_USE_CODE, 
  dbo.formDelimitedString (DISTINCT v_mie_all.TRANS_CODE) AS TRANS_CODE, 
  --dbo.formDelimitedString (DISTINCT v_mie_all.MI_FUNDS_MGR) AS MI_FUNDS_MGR,
  dbo.formDelimitedString (DISTINCT v_mie_all.EQ_FUNDS_MGR) AS EQ_FUNDS_MGR, 
  dbo.formDelimitedString (DISTINCT v_mie_all.CNTRCT_ARNGMT) AS CNTRCT_ARNGMT,
  dbo.formDelimitedString (DISTINCT v_mie_all.SU_ID) AS SU_ID
FROM v_mie_all
```

Here is the source for the function:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE [dbo].[FormDelimitedString]
(@value [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS[nvarchar](4000)
EXTERNAL NAME [FormDelimitedString].[SqlServerProject1.FormDelimitedString]
GO
```

Hmm maybe I can just increase nvarchar4000 to something bigger.

Comment: The problem is quite possibly in your .Net code. Regardless here's a method to do that purely in T-SQL which means you won't have to mess with CLR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048209/concatenating-column-values-into-a-comma-separated-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using this instead

```
SELECT Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT '|' + CAST(MY_COLUMN_NAME AS nvarchar)
 FROM   MY_TABLE_NAME 
 FOR xml path, type).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') AS MY_COLUMN_NAME,
```

The old code looked like:

```
SELECT dbo.formDelimitedString (DISTINCT MY_COLUMN_NAME) AS MY_COLUMN_NAME,
```