# subqueries in UPDATE SET (sql server 2005)

Tags: sql-server-2005, subquery

I have a question about using subqueries in an Update statement.  My example:

```
UPDATE TRIPS
   SET locations = city + ', ' FROM (select Distinct city 
                                       from poi 
                                      where poi.trip_guid = trips.guid)
```

Is it possible to refer to main table value (trips.guid) in subqueries?

When i try to use `trips.guid` I get the error:

> "The multi-part identifier "trips.guid" could not be bound."

The clause 'select Distinct city from poi' return more that one city.

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be only 1 city in poi for a trip_guid (or are you expecting it to handle this for you somehow)?

Comment: There are at least 2 cites. The idea is to put all cites in one field.

Comment: Your example works in Oracle. For SQL Server the other answers are applicable.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try something like

```
UPDATE  trips
SET     locations = t.city + ', ' + poi.city
FROM    trips t INNER JOIN
        (
            select Distinct city, trip_guid from poi
        ) poi ON t.trip_guid = poi.trip_guid
```

Comment: +1 although I don't agree with formatting - would put the `INNER JOIN` into the next line ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Another version.

```
UPDATE trips
SET locations = trips.city + ', ' + poi.city
FROM trips INNER JOIN poi
ON poi.trip_guid = trips.guid
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use constants and values from the outer select in the sub-select:

```
Update trips
Set locations = ( Select Distinct trips.city + ', ' + poi.city
                  From poi
                  Where poi.trip_guid = trips.guid )
```

We don't know how your tables look like, so I can only assume that `Distinct` will work for you that way (returning only one distinct `city` in the sub-query).

Comment: The subquery will  break if it returns more than 1 record

Comment: @Jimmie R. Houts: Correct. I was updating my answer the moment you posted your comment, thanks!

Comment: Did you actualy try this, it says **Incorrect syntax near 't'.**

Comment: @astander: Thanks for testing, removed the aliases and now it works for me.

Comment: @itdebeloper: Is there also a `city` field in `trips` or do you just want to concatenate the `city`-fields of `poi` separated by comma?

Comment: I just want to concatenate the city fields of poi.

Comment: @itdebeloper: This sounds quite different than your question. Have a look at this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-mssql-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-subquery

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution  - just move the subquery to the UDF :)

```
UPDATE TRIPS
   SET locations = getAllTripCity(guid);
```

My UDF's source code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getAllTripCity(
    @tripGuid uniqueidentifier
)
RETURNS nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @cities nvarchar(200);
 set  @cities = ''
 select @cities =  @cities + city + ' ' from (select DISTINCT city poi where poi.trip_guid = @tripGuid)
 return @ @cities;
END
```

That's all what you I need to do - works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the initial poster. My use case was the following:
One table contained Date and Time of a sport event. Because I am getting information from different sources, I changed the schema of the database so I had a int value for time and datetime (or maybe just date) for the date of the sport event.

This is my query:

```
UPDATE Matches 
SET StartTime= MatchTime.ThisMatchStartTime
FROM Matches AS M
INNER JOIN (SELECT CONVERT(int, CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(Hour, MatchDate)) + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(Minute, MatchDate)),2)) AS ThisMatchStartTime, MatchId
  FROM [Matches]
  WHERE SportTypeId=16) AS MatchTime ON M.MatchId=MatchTime.MatchId
WHERE StartTime > 2400
AND SportTypeId = 16;
```

Some explanation:
You have to give the subquery MatchStartTime a different name otherwise you get a warning/error from SQL Server.
I also had to add MatchId so I knew I was updating the correct Match.
The SportTypeId is used to separate different sports in the database.

Thanks to @astander for pointing me in the right direction. Without his post I would have struggled a bit more to end up with this solution.