# Update a table from a query in another table

Tags: sql, database, sql-update

```
UPDATE devicenumplanmap 
SET devicenumplanmap.e164mask = '+1' 
FROM devicenumplanmap 
WHERE (select devicenumplanmap.pkid, devicenumplanmap.e164mask 
       from devicenumplanmap, device 
       where devicenumplanmap.fkdevice = device.pkid 
         and device.name like '%RDP' 
         and devicenumplanmap.e164mask like '819%')
```

A syntax error has occurred.

We want to update the table devicenumplanmap from a search in another table.

Comment: Which RDBMS -- different flavors of sytax for each...

Comment: UPDATE devicenumplanmap 
SET devicenumplanmap.e164mask = '+1' 
FROM devicenumplanmap 
WHERE exists(select *
       from devicenumplanmap, device 
       where devicenumplanmap.fkdevice = device.pkid 
         and device.name like '%RDP' 
         and devicenumplanmap.e164mask like '819%')

Comment: Looks like an attempt on TSQL update syntax. SQL server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [subqueries in UPDATE SET (sql server 2005)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586517/subqueries-in-update-set-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`.  Depending on your RDBMS, the syntax is slightly different.

**MySQL:**

```
UPDATE devicenumplanmap d
    JOIN device de ON d.fkdevice = de.pkid
SET d.e164mask = '+1' 
WHERE de.name like '%RDP' 
       AND d.e164mask like '819%'
```

**SQL Server:**

```
UPDATE  d
SET d.e164mask = '+1' 
FROM devicenumplanmap d 
    JOIN device de ON d.fkdevice = de.pkid
WHERE de.name like '%RDP' 
       AND d.e164mask like '819%'
```

**More universal approach:**

```
UPDATE devicenumplanmap 
SET e164mask = '+1' 
WHERE e164mask like '819%' AND
    fkdevice IN (
        SELECT pkid
        FROM Device 
        WHERE name like '%RDP' 
)
```

Comment: Well! Thank you so much for that! It worked like a charm! I simply added concat ! It was a pleasure!
UPDATE devicenumplanmap 
SET e164mask = concat('+1',e164mask) 
WHERE e164mask like '418%' AND 
        fkdevice IN ( 
              SELECT pkid 
              FROM Device WHERE name like '%RDP' 
)

Comment: @DanikW.Therrien -- np, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
UPDATE devicenumplanmap 
SET devicenumplanmap.e164mask = '+1' 
FROM devicenumplanmap 
WHERE **exists(select ***
       from devicenumplanmap, device 
       where devicenumplanmap.fkdevice = device.pkid 
         and device.name like '%RDP' 
         and devicenumplanmap.e164mask like '819%')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for, easy and simple

```
UPDATE devicenumplanmap
SET devicenumplanmap.e164mask = '+1' 
FROM devicenumplanmap dp 
INNER JOIN device d
ON dp.fkdevice = d.pkid
WHERE d.name like '%RDP' 
and dp.e164mask like '819%'
```