# T-SQL, Select @variable within a sub-query causes syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using a sub-query to get results needed (multiple records returned), and I want to put those results in a single record returned.

When I run the sub-query on its own, it works, but once I use it as a sub query, it no longer works due to a syntax error.

The following code causes a syntax error

> (Incorrect syntax near '='.)

```
declare @test varchar(1000)
set @test = ''  

SELECT description, (SELECT @test = @test + FirstName
                FROM EMP_tblEmployee
                )select @test
FROM EMP_tblCrew
```

So essentially, the sub query

```
(SELECT @test = @test + FirstName
                    FROM EMP_tblEmployee
                    )select @test
```

returns "charliejohnjacob"

The main query

```
SELECT description FROM EMP_tblCrew
```

returns "janitor"

So I want it to say

> janitor | charliejohnjacob

2 fields, 1 record.

Comment: What do you want to do, in plain english ?

Comment: Are you trying to transform rows into columns, or add a space to firstName's

Comment: Looks like an attempt to concatenate all the first names into a result set... but why? This, if it works, will create first name pyramid of sorts. The intent here is highly questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not syntactically correct and the T-SQL parser has a nasty habit of not reporting an error quite accurately at times. This is a bit of a stab in the dark but try:

```
SELECT 
description, 
(SELECT FirstName + ' ' FROM EMP_tblEmployee FOR XML PATH('')) AS [Name Concat Result]
FROM EMP_tblCrew
```

That will fix one thing at least, though I'm not sure how SQL server feels about concatenating inline like that. You also risk overflowing the varchar(1000) if your table is of appreciable size. Even varchar 8000 isn't very much for this kind of query.

Comment: Hi, I just tried that, didn't work, same error.
declare @test varchar(1000)
set @test = '' 

SELECT description, (SELECT @test = @test + FirstName
    FROM EMP_tblEmployee
    ) as testing
from EMP_tblCrew

Comment: If you really want to concatenate names you might think about using a cursor or some CTE function. Please explain what you want to achieve. Better yet, mock up a result set of what you want.

Comment: You're missing the FROM clause in your comment's query.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy paste issue (was taking out the db names when posting here).

Comment: Updated the query to use FOR XML PATH('') for concatenation. Note that the variable is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching google for "SQL Concatenate rows into string". There are a number of useful solutions for this.

It looks like you also need to join the employee to the crew table, so that you dont get some cartesian product (usually not what is wanted).

Comment: This is embarrassing, I found a couple of questions similar to mine using your search criteria...  Thanks for the input.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-mssql-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-subquery

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest path involves using a recursive CTE (common table expression).  A detailed example of that is at https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Note, this basically requires that you have sql 2008.

Another path would be to create a user defined function that returned the concatenated values from the EMP_tblEmployee table.  You could do this in 2005 or 2008.