# I need SQL query for this data situation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data:

```
column1        column2
   1             aaa
   1             bbb
   2             ccc
   2             ddd
   2             eee
```

The expected output should be one row per column1 type which contains all of the column2 data, as below:

```
column1,   column2
   1,      aaa|bbb
   2,      ccc|ddd|eee
```

How can I get this output ?

I am Using below Query to get this data.

```
select sub_id,listagg(pack_name, '|')  within group(order by sub_id) package_name 
from Recon_Droppacks_Migration group by sub_id;

col1:sub_id
col2:pack_name
table:Recon_Droppacks_Migration
```

Comment: And post some working query, does not matter is incorrect, is a starting point

Comment: `select 1 as column1, 'aaa|bbb' as column2 union all
select 2 as column1, 'ccc|ddd|eee' as column2`

Comment: @MahmoudGamal: Yes, that's fairly obvious, but questions without at least an attempt at solving the problem don't usually get serious responses.

Comment: or another SQL Server answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815260/string-join-in-sql

Answer (score 4):

You did not specify the RDBMS you are using. So here is how you will do this in a variety of DBMS.

MySQL, you will use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT column1, GROUP_CONCAT(column2 SEPARATOR ' | ') column2
FROM table1
GROUP BY column1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d958/15)

In SQL Server, you will use [`FOR XML PATH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
select 
  t1.col1,
  STUFF((SELECT distinct ' | ' + col2
              from table1 t2
              where t1.col1 = t2.col1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE

            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,3,' ') col2
from table1 t1
group by t1.col1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d82bd/10)

In Oracle, you can use [`LISTAGG()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm):

```
select "col1", 
  listagg("col2", ' | ') within group(order by "col1") col2
from table1
group by "col1"
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ea2a/8)

In Postgresql you can use [`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
SELECT column1, string_agg(column2, ' | ') col2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY column1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3a1f7/2)

Edit, based on your comment, you will want to use:

```
select sub_id, listagg(pack_name, ' | ') within group(order by sub_id) package_name 
from Recon_Droppacks_Migration 
group by sub_id;
```

Comment: The Above Query got an error as "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected". Please help in getting this.

Comment: @Niranjan I am not sure why you would be getting this error, see this demo with both my original sample and your version working -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a2289/2 Is this the exact query you are running?

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL: Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT column1, GROUP_CONCAT(column2 SEPARATOR ' | ') as column2
    FROM Table1 
    GROUP BY column1
```

## [*See SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d958/18)

With SQL Server:

```
SELECT distinct column1, column2 = 
    STUFF((SELECT ' | ' + column2
           FROM Table1 b 
           WHERE b.column1 = a.column1 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM Table1 a
GROUP BY column1;
```

## [*See SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/954aa/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use a recursive query:

```
SELECT *, 
       Row_number() 
         OVER ( 
           PARTITION BY COLUMN1 
           ORDER BY COLUMN1 ) rn 
INTO   #TEMP1 
FROM   TABLE1; 

WITH RECUR 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Cast(COLUMN2 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS full_text 
         FROM   #TEMP1 
         WHERE  RN = 1 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT t1.*, 
                Cast(t2.FULL_TEXT + ' | ' + t1.COLUMN2 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
         FROM   #TEMP1 t1 
                INNER JOIN RECUR t2 
                        ON t1.COLUMN1 = t2.COLUMN1 
                           AND t1.RN = t2.RN + 1) 
SELECT t1.COLUMN1, 
       t1.FULL_TEXT 
FROM   RECUR t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(RN) rn, 
                          COLUMN1 
                   FROM   RECUR 
                   GROUP  BY COLUMN1) t2 
               ON t1.COLUMN1 = t2.COLUMN1 
                  AND t1.RN = t2.RN
```

See full example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c8a89/12)

Answer (score 0):

This solution [Does T-SQL have an aggregate function to concatenate strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031204/does-t-sql-have-an-aggregate-function-to-concatenate-strings/5031297#5031297) works fine, because it doesn't fail on xml characters.

```
declare @Temp_Table table (column1 bigint, column2 nvarchar(max))

insert into @Temp_Table (column1, column2)
select 1, 'aaa' union all
select 1, 'bbb' union all
select 2, 'ccc' union all
select 2, 'ddd' union all
select 2, 'eee'

select distinct
    t1.column1,
    stuff(
        (
            select
                ' | ' + t2.column2
            from @Temp_Table as t2
            where t2.column1 = t1.column1
            order by t2.column2 for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 3, '')
from @Temp_Table as t1
```

You can also write a cursor and use variable trick

Answer (score -1):

please try query given below

```
SELECT concat(CONVERT(column1,char(8))," , ") AS id,group_concat(CONVERT(column2, CHAR(20)) separator '|') AS result FROM `tablename` WHERE 1 group by column1
```

Here `concat` is using to append `,` with field `column1` and `CONVERT` is using to convert it into as string because it works on string better. and `GROUP_CONCAT` is using to append all result for particular `column1` with given saperator.

thanks