# update SQL Query using 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, concatenation

I have 3 tables

```
Table A
Account Id         Account Name
1                  Account1
2                  Account2
3                  Account3
```

Table B

```
  Opp ID            Partner Account ID
  O11               1
  O11               2
```

Table C

```
  Opp Id           Pstring
  O11
  O12
```

I want to update Table C  Pstring with account name, if there 2 account ids for same oppID then they should be appended with a semicolon between them and updated in Pstring

For example

- For Opp Id O11, Pstring should have `Account1;Account2`

How can I achieve this? Any pointer would be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample tables

```
create table A (AccountId int, AccountName varchar(100))
insert A select 1 ,'Account1'
insert A select 2 ,'Account2'
insert A select 3 ,'Account3'
create table B (OppID varchar(10), PartnerAccountID int)
insert B select 'O11', 1
insert B select 'O11', 2
create table C (OppId varchar(10), Pstring varchar(1000))
insert C (OppId) select 'O11'
insert C (OppId) select 'O12'
```

Create a function to concat account names for an OppID (one-off creation)

```
create function dbo.concatAccountName(@OppId varchar(10)) returns varchar(8000)
as
begin
declare @tmp varchar(8000)
select @tmp = isnull(@tmp+';','') + A.AccountName
from A
inner join B on A.AccountID = B.PartnerAccountID
where B.OppID=@OppId and A.AccountName is not null
return @tmp
end
GO
```

The update query

```
update C
set PString = dbo.concatAccountName(OppID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
UPDATE C
SET PString = X.PString
FROM
 (
   SELECT OppID, 
       (SELECT CAST(AccountName + ';' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
        FROM A 
        WHERE (A.AccountID = B.PartnerAccountID) 
        FOR XML PATH ('')
      ) AS PString
   FROM B
  ) X
WHERE X.OppID = C.OppID
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-sql-server-function-to-join-multiple-rows-from-a-sub) for more detials.

Comment: I am using Sql 2005 and i get an error "Incorrect syntax near 'MAX'."